# Comparing dissimilar types in python

Tags: python

First the code:

```
class myClass(object):
    def __cmp__(self, other):
        return cmp(type(self), type(other)) or cmp(self.__something, other.__something)
```

Does this produce the same ordering as for other types in python?  Is there a correct idiom
for this?

[Related question:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151658/python-hashable-dicts)

A bit of looking around on google I found some pertinent information in the [python docs](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons).  Quoting:

> **Implementation note:** Objects of
>   different types except numbers are
>   ordered by their type names; objects
>   of the same types that don’t support
>   proper comparison are ordered by their
>   address.

This suggests that If I want to follow that behavior, I should use

```
class myClass(object):
    def __cmp__(self, other):
        return (cmp(self.__class__.__name__, other.__class__.__name) or 
                cmp(self.__something, other.__something))
```

Especially unfortunate is that I may have an extraordinarily difficult time mantaining transitivity with `dict`s, which is a special case I had hoped to implement.

Do I even need to check the types of my arguments?  does python even let me see this?

Comment: Can you elaborate the question. What do you mean by 'produce the same ordering as for other types in python' ?

Comment: Note that cmp(dict(),str()) is nonzero.  I'd like to maintain transitivity with my type wrt predefined types, but I'm not sure how to actually do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python 2 unfortunately did support such "alien" comparisons (fortunately abrogated in Python 3). It's NOT easy to emulate the built-ins behavior because it has so many special cases, for example float and int compare directly (no type-comparison override as you have it coded) but complex makes any comparison (except == and !=) always raise an exception. Do you *really* need to emulate all of these quirks and wiggles? Such a need would be very unusual. If your type is "numeric" (e.g. look at decimal.Decimal) it needs to play nice with other numerical types, I guess, but types that aren't "comparable numbers" have fewer real-word sensible constraints...!

Answer (score 0):

What are you actually trying to do? Why would you want to sort or compare instances of different classes by class/type?

It's hard to propose a solution when you haven't actually posted the problem.

You need to define your own comparison methods for custom classes, and it's largely up to you to make sure any comparisons you perform make sense.

Please explain what you are trying to achieve. This might not be the Pythonic way.