# Add list to set

Tags: python, list, set

How do I add a list of values to an existing set?

Comment: Do you want to add the list to the set or the items in the list?

Comment: The list itself - I want to have a set of lists.

Comment: Seems the best-suited answer is the underrated one, suggesting using aSet.add(id(lst)) before adding lst itself to some list/queue/etc, to be sure that you did it ones. You should reconsider the accepted answer.

Answer (score 253, accepted):

You can't add a list to a set because lists are mutable, meaning that you can change the contents of the list after adding it to the set.

You can however add tuples to the set, because you cannot change the contents of a tuple:

```
>>> a.add(('f', 'g'))
>>> print a
set(['a', 'c', 'b', 'e', 'd', ('f', 'g')])
```

---

**Edit**: some explanation: The documentation defines a `set` as *an unordered collection of distinct hashable objects.* The objects have to be hashable so that finding, adding and removing elements can be done faster than looking at each individual element every time you perform these operations. The specific algorithms used are explained in the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_tree). Pythons hashing algorithms are explained on [effbot.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20200704001207/http://effbot.org/zone/python-hash.htm) and pythons `__hash__` function in the [python reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__).

Some facts:

- **Set elements** as well as **dictionary keys** have to be hashable
- Some unhashable datatypes:
- `list`: use `tuple` instead
- `set`: use `frozenset` instead
- `dict`: has no official counterpart, but there are some
  [recipes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151658/python-hashable-dicts)
- Object instances are hashable by default with each instance having a unique hash. You can  override this behavior as explained in the python reference.

Comment: And if you ever want to add a set to a set, use frozenset.

Comment: [`collections.namedtuple`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) might be considered "official" counterpart of the `dict`.

Comment: @Wahnfrieden: that is adding the *contents* of a set, not the set itself.

Comment: @aehlke: No, that adds the elements of the set to the first set, but we're talking about adding a set as an element of the first set.

Comment: perhaps a `OrdereDict` works for the `dict` case? From the `collections` lib?

Answer (score 917):

##### Adding the contents of a list

Use [`set.update()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.update) or the `|=` operator:

```
>>> a = set('abc')
>>> a
{'a', 'b', 'c'}

>>> xs = ['d', 'e']
>>> a.update(xs)
>>> a
{'e', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a'}

>>> xs = ['f', 'g']
>>> a |= set(xs)
>>> a
{'e', 'b', 'f', 'c', 'd', 'g', 'a'}
```

---

##### Adding the list itself

It is not possible to directly add the list itself to the set, since set elements must be [hashable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14535730/what-do-you-mean-by-hashable-in-python).

Instead, one may convert the list to a tuple first:

```
>>> a = {('a', 'b', 'c')}

>>> xs = ['d', 'e']
>>> a.add(tuple(xs))
>>> a
{('a', 'b', 'c'), ('d', 'e')}
```

Comment: set.update() adds the list to the set, correct?  what is the pipe equals operator for?

Comment: With respect to sets, the `|` operator implements the [set union operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_(set_theory)). Both the `|=` operator and `set.update()` method apply that operation in-place and are effectively synonymous. So, `set_a |= set_b` could be considered syntactic sugar for both `set_a.update(set_b)` *and* `set_a = set_a | set_b` (except that in the latter case, the same `set_a` object is reused rather than reassigned). `</ahem>`

Answer (score 98):

To **add the elements of a list to a set**, use `update`

From https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html

> s.update(t): return set s with elements added from t

E.g.

```
>>> s = set([1, 2])
>>> l = [3, 4]
>>> s.update(l)
>>> s
{1, 2, 3, 4}
```

If you instead want to **add the entire list as a single element** to the set, you can't because lists aren't hashable.  You could instead add a tuple, e.g. `s.add(tuple(l))`.  See also [TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' when using built-in set function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13464152/typeerror-unhashable-type-list-when-using-built-in-set-function) for more information on that.

Answer (score 46):

Hopefully this helps:

```
>>> seta = set('1234')
>>> listb = ['a','b','c']
>>> seta.union(listb)
set(['a', 'c', 'b', '1', '3', '2', '4'])
>>> seta
set(['1', '3', '2', '4'])
>>> seta = seta.union(listb)
>>> seta
set(['a', 'c', 'b', '1', '3', '2', '4'])
```

Answer (score 17):

Please notice the function `set.update()`. The documentation says:

> Update a set with the union of itself and others.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question (since the OP wants to add the list itself to the set) but it was the answer that I needed when Google brought me here :-)

Comment: Well, it seems like the most relevant answer to the question to me... for instance, if b = set([1]), b.update([7,25]) will give b the following value : set([1, 25, 7]) ---> Isn't it what we're looking for here?

Answer (score 9):

**list objects are unhashable**. you might want to turn them in to tuples though.

Answer (score 7):

Sets can't have mutable (changeable) elements/members. A list, being mutable, cannot be a member of a set.

As sets are mutable, you cannot have a set of sets!
You can have a set of frozensets though.

(The same kind of "mutability requirement" applies to the keys of a dict.)

Other answers have already given you code, I hope this gives a bit of insight.
I'm hoping Alex Martelli will answer with even more details.

Answer (score 6):

I found I needed to do something similar today. The algorithm knew when it was creating a new list that needed to added to the set, but not when it would have finished operating on the list.

Anyway, the behaviour I wanted was for set to use `id` rather than `hash`. As such I found `mydict[id(mylist)] = mylist` instead of `myset.add(mylist)` to offer the behaviour I wanted.

Answer (score 5):

You want to add a tuple, not a list:

```
>>> a=set('abcde')
>>> a
set(['a', 'c', 'b', 'e', 'd'])
>>> l=['f','g']
>>> l
['f', 'g']
>>> t = tuple(l)
>>> t
('f', 'g')
>>> a.add(t)
>>> a
set(['a', 'c', 'b', 'e', 'd', ('f', 'g')])
```

If you have a list, you can convert to the tuple, as shown above. A tuple is immutable, so it can be added to the set.

Answer (score 4):

You'll want to use tuples, which are hashable (you can't hash a mutable object like a list).

```
>>> a = set("abcde")
>>> a
set(['a', 'c', 'b', 'e', 'd'])
>>> t = ('f', 'g')
>>> a.add(t)
>>> a
set(['a', 'c', 'b', 'e', 'd', ('f', 'g')])
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I usually do it:

```
def add_list_to_set(my_list, my_set):
    [my_set.add(each) for each in my_list]
return my_set
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using `*` unpack, like below:

```
>>> a=set('abcde')
>>> a
{'a', 'd', 'e', 'b', 'c'}
>>> l=['f','g']
>>> l
['f', 'g']
>>> {*l, *a}
{'a', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'b', 'g', 'c'}
>>>
```

Non Editor version:

```
a=set('abcde')
l=['f', 'g']
print({*l, *a})
```

Output:

```
{'a', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'b', 'g', 'c'}
```

Comment: Seems like OP needs to create a set of lists. Your solution would create a set of elements. I don't think they're they same things. In your example, if `l` was equal to `['f', 'g', 'a']`, unpacking `l` would lose an `a`.

Answer (score 2):

Union is the easiest way:

```
list0 = ['a', 'b', 'c']

set0 = set()
set0.add('d')
set0.add('e')
set0.add('f')

set0 = set0.union(list0)

print(set0)
```

Output:

```
{'b', 'd', 'f', 'c', 'a', 'e'}
```