# TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' when using built-in set function

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I have a list containing multiple lists as its elements

```
eg: [[1,2,3,4],[4,5,6,7]]
```

If I use the built in set function to remove duplicates from this list, I get the error

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

The code I'm using is

```
TopP = sorted(set(TopP),reverse=True)
```

Where TopP is a list just like in the e.g. Above

Is this usage of set() wrong? Is there any other way in which I can sort the above list?

Comment: What would be your desired output for the list you provided?

Comment: @arshajii This seems like a bad example since there aren't any duplicates. But anyway, they probably want `[[4, 5, 6, 7], [1, 2, 3, 4]]`, which you can get from `sorted(TopP, reverse=True)` in this case.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Sets require their items to be *hashable*. Out of types predefined by Python only the immutable ones, such as strings, numbers, and tuples, are hashable. Mutable types, such as lists and dicts, are not hashable because a change of their contents would change the hash and break the lookup code.

Since you're sorting the list anyway, just place the duplicate removal *after* the list is already sorted. This is easy to implement, doesn't increase algorithmic complexity of the operation, and doesn't require changing sublists to tuples:

```
def uniq(lst):
    last = object()
    for item in lst:
        if item == last:
            continue
        yield item
        last = item

def sort_and_deduplicate(l):
    return list(uniq(sorted(l, reverse=True)))
```

Comment: +1 for the explanation, because sorting before uniquifying is easier than the other way around, and your answer doesn't require elements to be convertible to `tuple`. However, it isn't quite true that only immutable types are hashable—only immutable types, and mutable types where `a==b` implies `id(a)==id(b)` are hashable. (I forget the exact wording, but there are multiple questions on SO from people who found the wording confusing…)

Comment: @abarnert Yeah, saying that only immutable types are hashable is a bit of a simplification because it ignores objects that compare/hash by part of their state. (Objects that compare by identity can still be argued to be immutable as long as their useful state is captured by their identity — think interned enums and sentinels.)

Comment: Well, yes, but the Python documentation explicitly talks about mutable objects that compare by identity, so arguing that such objects should really be considered immutable just makes an already-confusing part of the docs even more confusing.

Comment: @abarnert Do you have a reference for that? The closest I could find was the [definition of *hashable*](http://docs.python.org/2.7/glossary.html#term-hashable), but it doesn't explicitly talk about mutable objects that compare by identity. The documentation of [`hash`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#hash) and [`dict`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) didn't help either.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy, under Dictionaries: "The only types of values not acceptable as keys are values containing lists or dictionaries or other mutable types that are compared by value rather than by object identity". If there were no such thing as mutable types that are compared by object identity, this distinction wouldn't be necessary, or even meaningful. IIRC, there's similar text once more in the reference, plus once in the tutorial.

Comment: Actually, the `dict` docs you linked make the same distinction: "mutable types (that are compared by value rather than by object identity)". I believe that if you go back to early 2.x, the docs gave user-defined (I think meaning classic) classes as an example of mutable types are are compared by identity, and therefore can be hashed, but that was stricken because it was misleading—user-defined classes aren't necessarily mutable, aren't necessarily compared by ID, and aren't necessarily hashable…

Comment: @abarnert Point taken, I missed the Dictionaries part where the manual does discuss types that compare by identity and calls them mutable. However, the `dict` docs I cited before apparently support my position: the wording *mutable types (that are compared by value rather than by object identity)* can be read to *define* mutable types as those that compare by value and not by identity. In that case, those that compare by identity would be immutable.

Comment: The clause is written in the form of a limiting relative clause: "mutable types" is a class, "that are compared…" selects a specific subclass or element from that class. Besides being how English normally works (if you want the other reading, say "those that are…"), it's consistent with the other docs, threads about this, etc. But I will agree that it's very badly worded. (Given how often all 3 mentions are misinterpreted or just lead to blank-stare responses, it would be silly to argue that they're clear.) Someone needs to put the effort into clarifying the docs.

Comment: @abarnert I've now changed the wording of the answer to narrow the claim to the types that come with Python. Discussing classes that define `__hash__` would unnecessarily encumber the answer.

Answer (score 28):

Sets remove duplicate items. In order to do that, the item can't change while in the set. Lists can change after being created, and are termed 'mutable'. You cannot put mutable things in a set.

Lists have an immutable equivalent, called a 'tuple'. This is how you would write a piece of code that took a list of lists, removed duplicate lists, then sorted it in reverse.

`result = sorted(set(map(tuple, my_list)), reverse=True)`

Additional note: If a tuple contains a list, the tuple is still considered mutable.

Some examples:

```
>>> hash( tuple() )
3527539
>>> hash( dict() )

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    hash( dict() )
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
>>> hash( list() )

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    hash( list() )
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: Thanks!! Here, is result a tuple or list ?

Comment: It's a list of tuples; you'll have to convert the elements back to lists.

Comment: @user1747696: Converting back to lists is as easy as converting to tuples: `result = map(list, sorted(set(map(tuple, my_list)), reverse=True))`. (At some point, you're going to want to break this up into multiple lines, with names for the intermediate steps…)

Comment: thanks a lot for your explanations arround set vs the mutable and immutable lists

Answer (score 4):

```
    python 3.2


    >>>> from itertools import chain
    >>>> eg=sorted(list(set(list(chain(*eg)))), reverse=True)
        [7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]


   ##### eg contain 2 list within a list. so if you want to use set() function
   you should flatten the list like [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7]

   >>> res= list(chain(*eg))       # [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7]                   
   >>> res1= set(res)                    #   [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
   >>> res1= sorted(res1,reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 4):

Definitely not the ideal solution, but it's easier for me to understand if I convert the list into tuples and then sort it.

```
mylist = [[1,2,3,4],[4,5,6,7]]
mylist2 = []
for thing in mylist:
    thing = tuple(thing)
    mylist2.append(thing)
set(mylist2)
```