# pandas drop_duplicates unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray', 'set' and 'list'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to use `drop_duplicates` on a column of a `dataframe`,

```
A          len
['1', '2'] 2
['1', '2'] 2
['3']      1
['4', '5'] 2 
['4', '5'] 2
```

The result `dataframe` should look like

```
A          len
['1', '2'] 2
['3']      1
['4', '5'] 2
```

I have tried `df.drop_duplicates('A', inplace=True)`, but got error,

```
unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

I have also converted `A` to lists and sets using `df['A'].apply(list)` and `df['A'].apply(set)`, and then using `drop_duplicates`, but all failed with `unhashable type: 'set' and 'list'`. I am wondering how to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need `tuple`:

```
df['A'].apply(tuple)
```

So use [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[~df['A'].apply(tuple).duplicated()]
print (df)
        A  len
0  [1, 2]    2
2     [3]    1
3  [4, 5]    2
```

Comment: it's clear that it works, but it is not clear for me why It is needed to convert in a tuple
Thank you in advance :)

Comment: @AndreaCiufo - You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13464194/2901002) for explain why some types cannot be  `unhashable type` like `list, array`

Comment: It's interesting that DataFrame duplicated method works differently from Series duplicated one. I can now use `list` and `set` in your example to get a working code, e.g. `df[~df['A'].apply(list).duplicated()]` is working but using similar method on DataFrame, e.g. `df["A"].apply(list).to_frame("A").duplicated("A")`, will fail.