# pandas: TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Tags: python, list, pandas, hash, duplicates

I have the following `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        [["John Muller"], "person", [8866155845]],
        [["Innovation Division"], "company", np.nan],
        [["Carol Sway"], "person", [8866155845]],
    ],
    columns=["name", "kind", "phone"],
)

# Out:
#                     name     kind         phone
# 0          [John Muller]   person  [8866155845]
# 1  [Innovation Division]  company           NaN
# 2           [Carol Sway]   person  [8866155845]
```

and I want to find duplicates of a phone number. But the objects in `df` are lists, so using:

```
df.duplicated('phone')
```

will generate the error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: Probably this can be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46958331/pandas-drop-duplicates-unhashable-type-numpy-ndarray-set-and-list

Comment: Did an answer below help? Feel free to accept an answer (green tick on left), or ask for clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use [`applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) function which is quite handy to solve this problem:

```
# get duplicated row
df2 = df[df.applymap(lambda x: x[0] if isinstance(x, list) else x).duplicated('phone')]

print(df2)

           name    kind         phone
2  [Carol Sway]  person  [8866155845]
```

Comment: what if we have both `list` and `dict`? can we use `applymap` with two if conditions? Thank you!

Comment: If you have arrays with more than 1 value you can convert them to tuples, which are hashable: `applymap(lambda x: tuple(x) if isinstance(x, list) else x)`

Answer (score 2):

You will be surprised that [pd.DataFrame.duplicated](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) works differently when compared to [pd.Series.duplicated](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html). You are right that `df.duplicated("phone")` will throw TypeError, but using `df.phone.duplicated()` directly will succeed.

```
df[df.phone.duplicated()]  # or df[df["phone"].duplicated()]

#           name    kind         phone
# 2  [Carol Sway]  person  [8866155845]
```

Another simple and useful way, how to deal with list objects in DataFrames, is using [explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) method which is transforming list-like elements to a row (but be aware it replicates index). You could use it in a following manner:

```
df_exploded = df.explode("phone")
df_exploded[df_exploded.duplicated("phone")]

#            name    kind       phone
# 2  [Carol Sway]  person  8866155845
```

Or if you are only interested in duplicated phone numbers, you can then do something like `df["phone"].explode().value_counts()` to see how many times are particular numbers duplicated.

Answer (score 1):

Use can use the [hashable_df](https://pypi.org/project/hashable-df/) package:

```py
from hashable_df import hashable_df
hashable_df(df).duplicated('phone')
```

This will make all unhashable cell values hashable and these kind of operations to work.

Answer (score 0):

We can deduce from this error that `df.duplicated` is using `set` to determine the duplicates, hence all objects in the series must be hashable. Lists are not hashable.

Examining your dataframe, each `name` and `phone` is a list with a single string.

Why? if there is not a good enough reason (ie, each row will never have more than a single name and phone) convert then to strings, or create them as strings from the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your series of single-item list items to a series of scalars. Since sometimes you have `NaN`, you can use a custom `lambda` function.

```
for col in ['name', 'phone']:
    df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: next(iter(x)) if isinstance(x, list) else x)
```

This will make your series items hashable and enable you to use `pd.DataFrame.duplicated`.