# Symmetric difference of two pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes. The columns are: 'x', 'y', 'name'.

They are the same for both of the two datasets.
The x and y are lists of their own. This is what one dataframe looks like

```
x ----- y------- name
 0  [0.4752243077637221, 0.6520124241756947, 0.468...  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...  D 1#0 ξ:3τ:0.1
 1  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...  [0.38764437658969714, 0.5140357108089131, 0.75...  D 1#1 ξ:3τ:0.1
 2  [0.20785203454036535, 0.1204140394378531, 0.22...  [0.8566063230698455, 0.8234990482161559, 0.826...  D 2#0 ξ:3τ:0.1
 3  [0.4752243077637221, 0.6520124241756947, 0.585...  [0.38764437658969714, 0.5140357108089131, 0.62...  D 2#1 ξ:3τ:0.1
 4  [0.7019329992171317, 0.9106333194078352, 0.786...  [0.7054927087841893, 0.8111061879179277, 0.845...  D 2#2 ξ:3τ:0.1
```

The second dataframe might have more or less rows and the name will vary. I want to check which x-y-coordinates are in both dataframes, independent of the row - and delete if it is a duplicate.

The goal is to depict the symmetric difference of a clustering algorithm

I already tried:

```
difference = pd.concat([all_clusters_a, all_clusters_b]).drop_duplicates(keep=False, inplace=False)
    enter code here
```

Which leads to: TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

and the same error with:

```
    all_clusters_a.iloc[1:4]= all_clusters_b[:3].values
all_clusters_a['a']='a'
all_clusters_a.set_index('a', append=True, inplace=True)
all_clusters_b['b']='b'
all_clusters_b.set_index('b', append=True, inplace=True)
mergeda = all_clusters_a.append(all_clusters_b)
mergeda = mergeda.drop_duplicates().sort_index()
idx = pd.IndexSlice
complement_BiA = mergeda.loc[idx[:,'a'],:]

mergedb = all_clusters_b.append(all_clusters_b)
mergedb = mergedb.drop_duplicates().sort_index()
complement_AiB = mergedb.loc[idx[:,'b'],:]
```

the numpy.ndarray seems to hate the drop_duplicate()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pandas drop\_duplicates unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray', 'set' and 'list'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46958331/pandas-drop-duplicates-unhashable-type-numpy-ndarray-set-and-list)

Comment: @JohnSloper, Not necessarily! The answer in the suggested link could convert only one column to a tuple. In this question we need to look at the paires of x and y together. The link could be helpful partially to convert each column but doesn't answer this question

Comment: @JohnSloper, Your link got me thinking which would run faster making tuples from arrays or listing the values. So I tried with a very small dataframe of 20 lines and making tuple is faster, I will add it to my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to split the ndarrays, put them in columns and then check for the duplicates:

```
dfx = pd.DataFrame(all_clusters_a['x'].values.tolist())
dfy = pd.DataFrame(all_clusters_a['y'].values.tolist())
df = pd.concat([dfx,dfy], axis=1)
```

You need to do the same for all_clusters_b and then compare the two for the duplicated rows.

It might be faster if you make tuples from the ndarrays:

```
dfx = all_clusters_a['x'].apply(tuple)
dfy = all_clusters_a['y'].apply(tuple)
df = pd.concat([dfx,dfy], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately your first suggestions throws the error Expected list, got numpy.ndarray

the second suggestion however seems to be working. The final result is currently looking like this:

```
    dfxa = all_clusters_a['x'].apply(tuple)
    dfya = all_clusters_a['y'].apply(tuple)
    dfa = pd.concat([dfxa,dfya], axis=1)

    dfxb = all_clusters_b['x'].apply(tuple)
    dfyb = all_clusters_b['y'].apply(tuple)
    dfb = pd.concat([dfxb,dfyb], axis=1)

    difference = pd.concat([dfa, dfb]).drop_duplicates(keep=False, inplace=False)
```