# Turning dictionary values into sets?

Tags: python, dictionary, set

How can I turn `dictionary1` into `dictionary2`?  Basically, I want to turn all the dictionary values into sets so that there are no duplicates in the dictionary values.

I tried to do `dictionary2 = set(dictionary1.values())`, but this function did not give me what I am looking for.

```
dictionary1 = {
    'cat': ['frog', 'frog'] ,
    'dog': ['deer', 'deer', 'deer', 'goat'],
    'bat': ['apes,' 'mice', 'mice'] }
```

and

```
dictionary2 = {
    'cat': ['frog'] ,
    'dog': ['deer', 'goat'],
    'bat': ['apes,' 'mice'] }
```

Comment: These are not sets, but lists with unique elements.

Comment: Iterate over the key,value pairs of `dictionary1.items()` and construct a new dictionary with `key:set(value)` pairs.

Comment: `a_set = set(dictionary.values())`

Answer (score 2):

```
dictionary1 = {'cat': ['frog', 'frog'] , 'dog': ['deer', 'deer', 'deer', 'goat'], 'bat': ['apes,' 'mice', 'mice'] }
dict2={i:list(set(dictionary1[i])) for i in dictionary1}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with calling `dictionary2 = set(dictionary1.values())` is that `dictionary1.values()` just returns a list of every value in dictionary1. Each of these values is itself a list (e.g. `['frog', 'frog']` is one element of the `.values()` list). Calling `set()` on a multi-dimensional list (which is what happens here) results in `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'` because `set()` only takes lists of immutable (hashable) objects, but lists are mutable. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13464152/typeerror-unhashable-type-list-when-using-built-in-set-function) for more.

Besides that, calling `set()` on `dictionary1.values()` would really just reduce the list of values so that no list of animals would be repeated. In other words `set([('mouse', 'mouse'), ('mouse', 'mouse')])` results in `{('mouse', 'mouse')}` rather than `{('mouse'), ('mouse')}`, which I believe is closer to what you are looking for. (Note: using tuples here as they are immutable)

What you want to do is call `set()` (and then cast back to list with `list()`) on *each* value in `dictionary1.values()` and do so inside a new dictionary. This can be done with a dictionary comprehension (analogous to the more common list comprehension).

Here is how this can be done by:

```
dictionary1 = {'cat': ['frog', 'frog'] , 'dog': ['deer', 'deer', 'deer', 'goat'], 'bat': ['apes', 'mice', 'mice'] }
dictionary2 = {key: list(set(value)) for key, value in dictionary1.items()}
```

The above code results in:

```
dictionary1 #=> {'cat': ['frog', 'frog'] , 'dog': ['deer', 'deer', 'deer', 'goat'], 'bat': ['apes', 'mice', 'mice'] }
dictionary2 #=> {'cat': ['frog'], 'dog': ['goat', 'deer'], 'bat': ['apes', 'mice']}
```

as desired.