# how to Define a new variable of type set and store the text list of words in it?

Tags: python, list, set, nltk

**code is **

```
lines_en = codecs.open(r'C:\Qur’an\english.txt','r','utf-8-sig').readlines()
for line in lines_en:
    tokens = line.split()
all_tokens =[]
for line in lines_en :
    tokens = line.split()
    all_tokens.append(tokens)
```

the error here

```
set(all_tokens)
```

File "", line 1, in 
    sorted(set(all_tokens))
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: Are the two loops a copying error?

Comment: why this error? --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/51359795/6660373

Comment: As the error states, `list` objects are not hashable. Are you trying to store *lists* in your set? Because you cannot, but you can convert to a `tuple`. Or, do you just want all the words?

Comment: Please share the entire error message.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' when using built-in set function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13464152/typeerror-unhashable-type-list-when-using-built-in-set-function)

Answer (score 2):

```py
    tokens = line.split()
    all_tokens.append(tokens)
```

tokens is a list.

all_tokens is a list of lists.

I guess what you want to do is aggregate all tokens in all_tokens, therefore extend all_tokens with tokens

```py
    tokens = line.split()
    all_tokens.extend(tokens)
```