# TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' in last code line

Tags: python

```
rm=[[],['COC1=C(C=C(C=C1)CC2=NC=CC3=CC(=C(C=C32)OC)OC)OC.Cl'],     ['C[C@@H]1[C@H]([C@@H]([C@@H]([C@@H](O1)OC\\2CC3C(C(CC(O3)(CC(CC(CC(CC(CC(=O)CC(CC(=O)OC(C(/C=C/C=C/C=C\\C=C/C=C/C=C/C=C2)C)C(C)CCC(CC(=O)C4=CC=C(C=C4)NC)O)O)O)O)O)O)O)O)C(=O)OC)O)N)O']]
smiles_dict=['CCCC1=NN(C2=C1N=C(NC2=O)C3=C(C=CC(=C3)C(=O)CN4CCN(CC4)CC)OCC)C', 'CCCC1=NN(C2=C1N=C(NC2=O)C3=C(C=CC(=C3)S(=O)(=O)N4CCN(CC4)CC)OCC)C']
nsmilesd = {}
nsmilesd= list(set(smiles_dict)-set(rm))
```

Error is shown for `set(rm)`. Can you help me understanding why?

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13464152/typeerror-unhashable-type-list-when-using-built-in-set-function) is similar and should be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is referring to the object hash which must not change throughout the run of the python program. Try decomposing that statement and you'll see that `set(rm)` fails. That list's elements are also lists and mutable things can't be hashed in python's use of the word here. That's because mutable things can be changed later, invalidating that hash.

Sets use the object hash to lookup values in the set. If the hash of the object changes, then like and unlike values can not longer be determined.

I'm not sure what `rm` is supposed to be, but it looks like it has single item lists and its those items that should be in the set operation.

```
rm=[[],['COC1=C(C=C(C=C1)CC2=NC=CC3=CC(=C(C=C32)OC)OC)OC.Cl'],     ['C[C@@H]1[C@H]([C@@H]([C@@H]([C@@H](O1)OC\\2CC3C(C(CC(O3)(CC(CC(CC(CC(CC(=O)CC(CC(=O)OC(C(/C=C/C=C/C=C\\C=C/C=C/C=C/C=C2)C)C(C)CCC(CC(=O)C4=CC=C(C=C4)NC)O)O)O)O)O)O)O)O)C(=O)OC)O)N)O']]
smiles_dict=['CCCC1=NN(C2=C1N=C(NC2=O)C3=C(C=CC(=C3)C(=O)CN4CCN(CC4)CC)OCC)C', 'CCCC1=NN(C2=C1N=C(NC2=O)C3=C(C=CC(=C3)S(=O)(=O)N4CCN(CC4)CC)OCC)C']

rm2 = []
for lst in rm:
    rm2.extend(lst)
nsmilesd = {}
nsmilesd= list(set(smiles_dict)-set(rm2))
```