# Im trying to compare 2 lists that are from user input but it gi

Tags: python, list, input, set

```
liste0 = []
liste1 = []
s1 = input("kişileri gir")
s2 = input("kişileri gene gir")
s1 = s1.split(",")
s2 = s2.split(",")
liste0.append(s1)
liste1.append(s2)
print(set(liste0) ^ set(liste1))
```

**#error is: TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'**

Comment: Mention what you want to achieve.

Comment: Post the entire error (i.e. at which line it occurs)

Comment: Possible duplication: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13464152/typeerror-unhashable-type-list-when-using-built-in-set-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean to use `extend` instead of `append`?

```
liste0.extend(s1)
liste1.extend(s2)
```

When you use `append`, you have a nested list. For example, if you enter `1,2,3` at your first prompt, you get `list0 = [['1', '2', '3']]`, because it appended the split input as a list as **a single element** to the empty list.

But you cannot have lists inside of sets, for example:

```
print(set([0, 1, 2]))
# {0, 1, 2}

print(set([0, [1, 2]]))
# TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

From the [`set()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) docs:

> Return a new set or frozenset object whose elements are taken from iterable. The elements of a set must be hashable.

From the [`hashable`](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-hashable) docs:

> Most of Python’s immutable built-in objects are hashable; mutable containers (such as lists or dictionaries) are not; immutable containers (such as tuples and frozensets) are only hashable if their elements are hashable.

Comment: You might want to explain why this possibly solves the problem.

Comment: I understood it well thank you very much. I have another small question. Is there any other way that is less complicated to compare 2 lists without using a set?

Comment: @Gladiones You can also do it with list comprehensions, but using sets is efficient and Pythonic. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3462143/967621