# Convert string to name of variable?

Tags: python, variables, python-itertools

I have this code:

```
all_list_combinations = itertools.product(#here must be variables)
```

the amount of variables< every time is different so i can't just put variables. So, can I convert name of variables from string to variable or can I put any other code

I tried use compile() but it didn't work

Comment: Could you explain why "the amount of variables is different every time"? If your variables are in a list there is no problem feeding this list to `product`. If you have `data = [[1, 2, 3], ['A', 'B', 'C']]` you can do `all_list_combinations = itertools.product(*data)`. And this will work with other lists like `[[1, 2, 3], ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['z', 'y']]` too.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `eval` to evaluate the variable by its name:

```py
my_variable = ...
varible_name = "my_variable"
all_list_combinations = itertools.product(eval(varible_name))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Can I ask you one more thing? ```all_list_combinations = set(all_list_combinations)```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' i get this error

Comment: Please refer to this question: [TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' when using built-in set function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13464152/13253010)

Comment: Please read and understand "[Eval really is dangerous](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html)".  If you don't know what exactly `eval` does, you shouldn't use it. And if you understand what `eval` does, you don't want to use it.