# "Series objects are mutable and cannot be hashed" error

Tags: python, pandas, typeerror

I am trying to get the following script to work. The input file consists of 3 columns: gene association type, gene name, and disease name.

```
cols = ['Gene type', 'Gene name', 'Disorder name']
no_headers = pd.read_csv('orphanet_infoneeded.csv', sep=',',header=None,names=cols)

gene_type = no_headers.iloc[1:,[0]]
gene_name = no_headers.iloc[1:,[1]]
disease_name = no_headers.iloc[1:,[2]]

query = 'Disease-causing germline mutation(s) in' ###add query as required

orph_dict = {}

for x in gene_name:
    if gene_name[x] in orph_dict:
        if gene_type[x] == query:
            orph_dict[gene_name[x]]=+ 1
        else:
            pass
    else:
        orph_dict[gene_name[x]] = 0
```

I keep getting an error that says:

> Series objects are mutable and cannot be hashed

Any help would be dearly appreciated!

Comment: show us the full traceback so we can see the line on which the error is being thrown.  my guess is it's `orph_dict[gene_name[x]] = 0`.  the traceback would also show us the class of error being thrown.

Answer (score 39):

Shortly: `gene_name[x]` is a mutable object so it cannot be hashed. To use an object as a key in a dictionary, python needs to use its hash value, and that's why you get an error.

Further explanation:

Mutable objects are objects which value can be changed.
For example, `list` is a mutable object, since you can append to it. `int` is an immutable object, because you can't change it. When you do:

```
a = 5;
a = 3;
```

You don't change the value of `a`, you create a new object and make `a` point to its value.

Mutable objects cannot be hashed. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14535730/what-do-you-mean-by-hashable-in-python).

To solve your problem, you should use immutable objects as keys in your dictionary. For example: `tuple`, `string`, `int`.

Answer (score 13):

```
gene_name = no_headers.iloc[1:,[1]]
```

This creates a DataFrame because you passed a list of columns (single, but still a list). When you later do this:

```
gene_name[x]
```

you now have a Series object with a single value. You can't hash the Series.

The solution is to create Series from the start.

```
gene_type = no_headers.iloc[1:,0]
gene_name = no_headers.iloc[1:,1]
disease_name = no_headers.iloc[1:,2]
```

Also, where you have `orph_dict[gene_name[x]] =+ 1`, I'm guessing that's a typo and you really mean `orph_dict[gene_name[x]] += 1` to increment the counter.

Comment: How could I apply this technique of creating the Series from the start when I am splitting into a training and testing dataset?

`X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(training_feature_set, training_feature_label, test_size = 0.1, random_state=42)` @http://stackoverflow.com/users/639792/jkitchen

Comment: @Alvis, if your function returns DataFrames, you can still select individual items from those. Read the [docs for indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html). `.loc` or `.iloc` are probably what you want.

Comment: Thank you @jkitchen I'll check out the documentation :-)