# TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed problemwith column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem with a column of my dataframe but I don't understand why there are trouble on my column cat.[image]

[image]

Comment: `df_cat_tot['cat'].unique()` You are attempting to use `.cat` which is a reserved method for pandas.  You must use `['cat']` to access that column.

Comment: In the future, please post your dataframe as text, not as an image, same goes for output/errors.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i try with df_cat_tot['cat'].unique() but I ve the same error

Comment: Can you please post the output of `{type(i) for i in df_cat_tot['cat'].values}`?

Comment: please paste your code as text, it will help to debug the code

Comment: Input: {type(i) for i in df_cat_tot['cat'].values}
Output: {pandas.core.series.Series, str}

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Series objects are mutable and cannot be hashed" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29700552/series-objects-are-mutable-and-cannot-be-hashed-error)

Answer (score 2):

Your series contains other `pd.Series` objects. This is bad practice. In general, you should ensure your series is of a fixed type to enable you to perform manipulations without having to check for `type` explicitly.

Your error is due to `pd.Series` objects not being hashable. One workaround is to use a function to convert `pd.Series` objects to a hashable type such as `tuple`:

```
s = pd.Series(['one string', 'another string', pd.Series([1, 2, 3])])

def converter(x):
    if isinstance(x, pd.Series):
        return tuple(x.values)
    else:
        return x

res = s.apply(converter).unique()

print(res)

['one string' 'another string' (1, 2, 3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df_cat_tot['cat'].unique()
```

This will help you to recover from this error.
Both syntaxes are correct.