# Filter dataframe based on difference been two series, one mapped via dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe, indexing

I have my dictionary

```
d = {'A':1, 'B':2, 'C':3}
```

and my dataframe

```
df =pd.DataFrame({
"col1": ["A", "B", "C"],
"col2": [1, 2, 3],
"col3": [2, 1, 4] })
```

I search to compare each value in df with the correspondant value in the dictionary. If it matches the value is kept, otherwise the value is drop.

I try

```
m = df['col2'] >= d[df['col1']]
df.where(m, df, other = "")
```

But it get this error code for m: TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed...

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Post your error

Comment: TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

Comment: Yep. Apply should fix that

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Series objects are mutable and cannot be hashed" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29700552/series-objects-are-mutable-and-cannot-be-hashed-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new column for comparison using apply

```
df[‘dict_col’] = df[‘col1’].apply(lambda k: d[k])

m = df[‘dict_col’] >= df[‘col2’]

df[‘col2’] = df[‘col2’].where(m, df, other = "")
```

Comment: thanks ! But the whole row is erased, not just the value.

Comment: Updated to replace those values with ‘’

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pd.Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) with [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and Boolean indexing:

```
df = df.loc[df['col2'] >= df['col1'].map(d)]
```

Comment: But the whole row is erased, not just the value.

Comment: @Billy, Nope, that means either the data is wrong or you are applying the logic incorrectly.

Comment: i do not understand

Answer (score 1):

Hint is there in error message itself.

> TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed.

`df['col1']` is a [`Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.Series.html) object, which is a mutable object.

Mutable objects cannot be hashed and hence cannot be used as a dictionary key. From [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

> ... **dictionaries are indexed by keys, which can be any immutable type**; strings and numbers can always be keys...

You are using `Series` object as dictionary key. *One* way to rewrite `d[df['col1']]` is:

```
[d[x] for x in df['col1']]
```

Comment: thanks, it's clear, I have understood my mistake (and reread the documentation). But the result of my condition is still applying to the whole row. I do not get why.