# Removing duplicates from list - "TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed."

Tags: python, immutability, mutable

I have been receiving "TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed." And while I understand what it means, I can't seem to work out a solution. I have tried converting the series to a tuple (as seen below) since tuples are immutable. I am receiving the same error message. Any idea how I can fix this problem?

```
import pandas as pd

data_file = pd.read_csv("file:///C:/Users/carte/OneDrive/Desktop/TEST.csv")

Jordan = []
Carter = []
Reece = []
Liam = []
Bryce = []
David = []

Jordan = data_file['Jordan']
Carter = data_file['Carter']
Reece = data_file['Reece']
Liam = data_file['Liam']
Bryce = data_file['Bryce']
David = data_file['David']

invite = []
invite.append(Carter)
invite.append(Jordan)
invite.append(Reece)
invite.append(David)
invite.append(Liam)
invite.append(Bryce)

tuple(invite)

invite = list(dict.fromkeys(invite))
print(invite)
```

For some context, my code is supposed to take all of the names on each list and remove the duplicates before printing a single list at the end.

Comment: Tuples themselves are immutable, but if they contain a mutable object, then you're going to run into the same problem.

Comment: Can you flesh out your question with the actual stacktrace (error) and a snippet or example of what `TEST.csv` looks like?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Series objects are mutable and cannot be hashed" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29700552/series-objects-are-mutable-and-cannot-be-hashed-error)

Comment: Jordan = data-file['Jordan'] is creating a [Series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29700552/series-objects-are-mutable-and-cannot-be-hashed-error) and as the error says you cannot has a series. Follow the link to separate the column data into list correctly.

Comment: `tuple(invite)` doesn't actually do anything since you don't assign it to anything.

Answer (score 1):

As Makoto suggests, the issue is not the type of `invite`, but the type of what's going into `invite`. It looks like you're trying to unpack each instance of `pandas.Series` to fill the list before de-duplicating with `dict.fromkeys()`. For this, you should use `list.extend()` rather than `list.append()`. The former expands a list with all of the elements inside its argument, while the latter adds a single new element to a list ([Difference between append vs. extend list methods in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252703/difference-between-append-vs-extend-list-methods-in-python)). For example:

```py
invite = []
invite.extend(Carter)
invite.extend(Jordan)
```

You might also need to manually convert the `pandas.Series` into lists, which would look something like this:

```py
invite = []
invite.extend(Carter.to_list())
invite.extend(Jordan.to_list())
```

Note that creating empty lists before extracting data from the CSV should be unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a number of different ways to do this, so here's one option and this cuts down on the amount of code you need significantly.

```
# Assuming 'invites' is a list of strings that needs to be reduced to uniques
# This method will maintain the order of your list, but remove duplicates
uniques = list({key:'' for key in invites}.keys())

# Using set() will remove duplicates but will not preserve the order of the entries
uniques = list(set(invites))
```