# Joining excel rows to a single string to be used in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am new to Pandas.

I have and excel file with 10 sheets in it. I am trying [to achieve this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59581043/checking-if-value-in-pandas-dataframe-series-exists-in-excel-sheets?noredirect=1#comment105331620_59581043).

As no answers were provided on that question I am going to use this method to check if a string in a DataFrame row contains a word from excel sheet:

```
file = pd.read_excel(open('config_values.xlsx', 'rb'),
                     sheet_name='ContainsFree')
```

1. Join all rows in excel sheet using `first_sheet = '|'.join(file)`
2. Using :

```
df['Contains Language'] = df.Search_Query.str.contains(first_sheet, regex=True)
```

However, when I use `'|'.join(file)` I get the first row of the excel sheet rather than the joined string:

**excel_sheet_1**

```
gratuit
free
gratis
...
```

After `'|'join.(file)` I get:

```
gratuit
```

Expected:

```
gratuit|free|gratis
```

What am I doing wrong in order to join all rows in an excel sheet?

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: you dont need `open` when using `read_excel`

Comment: Thank you, but still I cant join all the rows in to a single string using `'|'.join(file)`, I only get the first entry of the sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
file = pd.read_excel('config_values.xlsx', sheet_name='ContainsFree', header=None)
'|'.join(file[0].astype(str))

'gratuit|free|gratis'
```

Comment: That worked, just added `file = '|'.join(file[0])`, thank you.

Comment: Would you mind helping with joining `ints`? I get an error: `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found`, when I use `containsYear = '|'.join(str(containsYear[0]))` I get `0| | | | | |2|0|1|0|`. When I try to join `2001,2002,2003,...`

Comment: @JonasPalačionis I edited my answer. Try to add `astype(str)`