# Split a column in df by another column value

Tags: python, pandas

In python, I have the following df (headers in first row):

```
FullName          FirstName
'MichaelJordan'   'Michael'
'KobeBryant'      'Kobe'
'LeBronJames'     'LeBron'
```

I am trying to split each record in "FullName" based on the value in "FirstName" but am not having luck...

This is what I tried:

```
df['Names'] = df['FullName'].str.split(df['FirstName'])
```

Which produces error:

```
'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

Desired output:

```
print(df['Names'])

['Michael', 'Jordan']
['Kobe', 'Bryant']
['LeBron', 'James']
```

Comment: Can you post the required sample output which you want?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29700552/series-objects-are-mutable-and-cannot-be-hashed-error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### `str.replace`

```
lastnames = [full.replace(first, '') for full, first in zip(df.FullName, df.FirstName)]
df.assign(LastName=lastnames)

        FullName FirstName LastName
0  MichaelJordan   Michael   Jordan
1     KobeBryant      Kobe   Bryant
2    LeBronJames    LeBron    James
```

---

Same exact idea but using `map`

```
df.assign(LastName=[*map(lambda a, b: a.replace(b, ''), df.FullName, df.FirstName)])

        FullName FirstName LastName
0  MichaelJordan   Michael   Jordan
1     KobeBryant      Kobe   Bryant
2    LeBronJames    LeBron    James
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

since you are making row wise operations we can use apply,

the idea is is to replace the first name with it self + a comma to split it by

```
df["SplitName"] = df.apply(
    lambda x: x["FullName"].replace(x["FirstName"], f"{x['FirstName']}, "), axis=1
)


print(df['SplitName'].str.split(',',expand=True))

         0        1
0  Michael   Jordan
1     Kobe   Bryant
2   LeBron    James
```

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> df.assign(names=[[firstname, fullname[len(firstname):]] 
                     for fullname, firstname in df[['FullName', 'FirstName']].values])
        FullName FirstName              names
0  MichaelJordan   Michael  [Michael, Jordan]
1     KobeBryant      Kobe     [Kobe, Bryant]
2    LeBronJames    LeBron    [LeBron, James]
```

Comment: Clever... given that first names are typically... uh.. first (-:

Answer (score 0):

This is oneliner with an apply. Split the `FullName` on the length of the `FirstName`:

```py
df['Names'] = df.apply(lambda row: [row['FullName'][:len(row['FirstName'])], row['FullName'][len(row['FirstName']):]] if row['FullName'].startswith(row['FirstName']) else '', axis=1)
```

```
        FullName FirstName              Names
0  MichaelJordan   Michael  [Michael, Jordan]
1     KobeBryant      Kobe     [Kobe, Bryant]
2    LeBronJames    LeBron    [LeBron, James]
```