# access to a dictionary value by passing a value from a pandas dataframe as dictionary key

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

There is a pandas df and a dictionary that its keys have gotten from this df. for example:

```
data = {'Type': [1, 1, 2, 3, 2] ,
    'Vol' : [10, 20, 15, 15, 15] ,
    'Cost' : [500, 300, 200, 250, 400] , 
    'IsSold' : [1, 1, 1, 1, 0]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

capacity = {key : 500 for key in df.Type.unique()}
```

A sub_dataframe will create with only one row of data:

```
sample_df = df.sample()
```

Now, I want to do this:

```
if sample_df['Cost'] <= capacity[sample_df['Type']] :
   #some procedure
```

But it returns an error when I run it:

```
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

Can you help me with it?

Comment: `sample_df['Type']` is a Series, hence the error when using it in `[]`

Comment: Why do you need to create a dictionary if all the keys get "500" as value? Just do `sample_df.mask(sample_df["Cost"] <= 500)`

Comment: `sample_df['Type'].iloc[0]`, https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#selection-by-position

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29700552/series-objects-are-mutable-and-cannot-be-hashed-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29700552/series-objects-are-mutable-and-cannot-be-hashed-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both LHS and RHS expressions are Pandas Series—not 'a value from a pandas data frame'. One of the possible solutions, is to get the index of the Series that has been sampled, and use it to retrieve values:

```
index = sample_df.index[0]
sample_df['Cost'][index] <= capacity[sample_df['Type'][index]]
```

The error states that the object of type Series cannot be used as a key of a dictionary, because it's mutable. Mutable objects in Python can't be hashed and thus, can't be used as dictionary keys.