# Python: Better way to compare two lists?

Tags: python

Please dont give me minus. I want to ask a better method to solve this problem, because what I am doing now is becoming a huge burden for me.

Hier is my question: I have two lists. I want to make sure that none item from one list is in the other list.

In Python I have been working with the following lines... (Assuming List_s has 3 items.)

```
if List_s[0] not in List_big and List_s[1] not in List_big and List_s[2] not in List_big:   #none item from List_s should be in List_big
    do something
else:
    pass
```

These lines were actually OK for me, till I suddenly realize that I have to work with lists with >200 length. And I have a lot of lists to compare.

So how could I change the code? Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: `any(x in List_big for x in List_s)` That is going to be a polynomial time, though. Probably better to make a `set` out of `List_big` so that can be linear time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert one of the lists to a `set` and use [`set.intersection`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set.intersection):

```
if not set(List_s).intersection(List_big):
    print('no common items between lists')
```

Note that the elements in both lists must be [hashable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14535739/353852).

Comment: If the elements are hashable.

Comment: Thank you! That is way better than mine!

Answer (score 2):

You will get the same results whether you use:

```
set(List_s).isdisjoint(List_big)
```

or:

```
not set(List_s).intersection(List_big)
```

But [set.isdisjoint](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set.isdisjoint) is much faster.  On my computer, `isdisjoint` takes about 150 nanoseconds to run against test data, while `intersection` takes 95 microseconds to run against the same data--about 630 times slower!

Answer (score 1):

For very large list,

```
import timeit
import random

L=[random.randrange(2000000) for x in xrange(1000000)]
M=[random.randrange(2000000) for x in xrange(1000000)]

start_time = timeit.default_timer()
print any(x in M for x in L)
#True
print timeit.default_timer() - start_time
#0.00981207940825

start_time = timeit.default_timer()
print not set(L).isdisjoint(M)
#True
print timeit.default_timer() - start_time
#0.164795298542

start_time = timeit.default_timer()
print True if set(L) & set(M) else False
#True
print timeit.default_timer() - start_time
#0.436377859225

start_time = timeit.default_timer()
print True if set(L).intersection(M) else False
#True
print timeit.default_timer() - start_time
#0.368563831022
```

Clearly,

```
print any(x in M for x in L)
```

is much more efficient

Comment: Thank you so much!