# Python: Dictionary key name that changes dynamically in a loop

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, key

My minimal working example is the following: I have a loop iterating a certain number of times. At each iteration, I would like to create a new key with a name depending on the current index value, for instance key_j, and assign a certain value to it. Is there a way to do this?

```
for j in range(10):
    dict[key_j] = j**2
```

Thank you

Comment: `key_j = f(j)` => you're done. (f transforms j into something else, string or integer or float or tuple,... hashable)

Comment: Something like `dictionary[j] = j ** 2`?

Comment: @Matthias the point is that "key" is actually a name I really need in the dictionary!

Comment: `new_dict = {'key_{}'.format(j): j**2 for j in range(10)}` ? Unless you're trying to refer to a variable `key_j`

Comment: But I need this key for different values (the dictionary is much larger)

Comment: You need to explain the problem in more detail - what do you mean you 'need this key'? Can you give an example of the required dataset?

Comment: When you say "name", do you mean "string"?

Comment: using `dict` as variable name is not a good practice, it's a type name.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use string formatting to create a string key with the current loop index

```
res = {}
for j in xrange(10):
    key_j = 'key_{}'.format(j)  # a string depending on j
    res[key_j] = j**2
```

The resulting `res` dictionary is:

```
{'key_5': 25, 'key_4': 16, 'key_7': 49, 'key_6': 36, 
 'key_1': 1, 'key_0': 0, 'key_3': 9, 'key_2': 4, 'key_9': 81, 
 'key_8': 64}
```

Note that dictionary keys are **not** ordered. If you want to keep the order, you need to use `OrderedDict` instead of regular `dict`.

BTW,
dictionary keys do not have to be strings, you can use `int` as keys as well (in fact every ["hashable"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14535739/1714410) object can be used as a key):

```
res = {}
for j in xrange(10):
    res[j] = j**2 # int as key
```

Resulting with:

```
{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 4, 3: 9, 4: 16, 5: 25, 6: 36, 7: 49, 8: 64, 9: 81}
```

In this example the keys are ordered, but it is **not** guaranteed to be so.

---

Note that you can create `res` dictionary using [dictionary comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14507637/1714410), for example:

```
res = {j: j**2 for j in xrange(10)}
```

or

```
res = {'key_{}'.format(j): j**2 for j in xrange(10)}
```

Answer (score 2):

this will wok simply,

```
for j in range(10):
    # since your key format is simple you can write in one line
    dict['key_%s'%j] = j**2
```

> Try to rename dict since it is type it is not good practice to use as variable name

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pythons` [f strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) to generate keys based on the index and then use these keys to create  dictionary as follows

```js
my_dict = {}
for j in range(4):
  key = f'key_{j}'
  my_dict[key] = j**2
  
print(my_dict)
#{'key_0': 0, 'key_1': 1, 'key_2': 4, 'key_3': 9,}
```