# Why is the dictionary key not changing

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

```
a = (1,2)  
b = {a:1}  
print(b[a]) # This gives 1  
a = (1,2,3)  
print(b[a]) # This gives error but b[(1,2)] is working fine
```

What I understood is python doesn't run garbage collector after a is changed to (1,2,3) as the tuple (1,2,3) is created as a new object and the tuple (1,2) is still being referenced in b.

What I didn't understood is why 'b' doesn't change the key after 'a' is changed

Answer (score 2):

`b = {a:1}` creates a dictionary with the value of `a` as a key and `1` as a value. When you **assign** a value to a, you create a new value, and `b` retrain the old value as its key.

The following example, using [id](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id), may illustrate it:

```
>>> a = (1,2)
>>> b = {a:1}
>>> id(a)
139681226321288
>>> a = (1,2,3)
>>> id(a)
139681416297520
>>> id(b.keys()[0])
139681226321288
```

Comment: shouldn't b update its key from (1,2) to (1,2,3).
I don't know if this would be a good practice or not.

Comment: @Arjunsingh Maybe you want to read this about [Python names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Comment: @Piinthesky that article makes more sense... :)

Answer (score 1):

Integers, floats, strings, tuples in python are immutable. A dictionary would allow only those keys which would be [hashable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14535730/what-do-you-mean-by-hashable-in-python) (immutable built-in objects are hashable). As @Mureinik correctly specified the reason behind the cause, I would give you another example where you can mutate the data by the process you followed above.

```
>>> l = [1,2,3]
>>> b = {'3' : l}
>>> b
{'3': [1, 2, 3]}
>>> l.append(5)
>>> l
[1, 2, 3, 5]
>>> b
{'3': [1, 2, 3, 5]}
```

But you cannot change the *keys* of a dictionary as they are hashed (only values can be updated). You either have to delete existing key-value pair or add new pair.

Comment: Ok...Now I got it. changing the key would require the dictionary to change the hashmap referring to the value which would then make the dictionary take more time.