# Hashing Custom Objects

Tags: python, hash

hash() method in python can match all immutable objects to unique hash value. However, I cannot understand the behavior of hash() method for objects of user-defined classes. Some of the resources say that if user-defined class do not contain `__hash__()` and `__eq__()` methods, that object cannot be hashed. On the other hand, the others claim the opposite one.

In other words, what is the role of `__eq__()` and `__hash__()` methods in order to hash custom objects ?

Comment: Custom methods => custom implementation. No custom methods => default implementation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do you mean by hashable in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14535730/what-do-you-mean-by-hashable-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

Basically, 'hash' should be quick, and act as a "triage" calculation to quickly know if two objects are *not* equal.

The 'eq'(uality) function is the function that tells if the objects are definitely equal or not. Maybe this function has to perform a lot of checks ( for instance if you want to define the equality of your objects by the equality of every member fields).

The purpose of these two functions is to have a quick way of saying "no, they are not equal" (the hash function), since the comparisons are often used a lot and most often two objects are not "equal".

Instead of executing a lot of "eq" functions, you execute a lot of quick "hash" functions, and if both the hashes match, the "eq" is executed to confirm the equality or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't implement [`__hash__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__), [`hash()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hash) will use the default implementation. If you don't implement [`__eq__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__), the default implementation will be used when you compare two instances.

```
class C:
    pass

class D:
    def __hash__(self):
        return 1

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return True

print(hash(C()))  # changing for every C instance
print(C() == C()) # False since objects are different

print(hash(D()))  # always 1
print(D() == D()) # always True
```