# combine the columns into unique values using 'set' function

Tags: python

I am trying to get the unique values from a list into a different column using 'set' function in the python 3. However I am getting the error: "TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed". What am I doing wrong here?

Sample Data:

```
id,food 1,food 2,food 3
1,,apples,mango
2,oranges,grapes,oranges
3,bananas,,apples
```

Code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('food.csv')
df

# pass
list(set(['apples','apples','oranges']))
# answers: ['apples', 'oranges'] #working

# fails if I pass in a dataframe columns. Why?
df['food_all'] = list(set([df['food 1'],df['food 2'],df['food 3']]))
df['food_all']
```

output like (ignoring spaces/null values...etc):

```
id,food_all
1,['apples','mango']
2,['oranges','grapes']
3,['bananas','apples']
```

Comment: Have you tried converting the individual columns (`df['food 1']`) into lists ie - `list(df['food 1'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
df = pd.read_csv('food.csv')

df['food_all'] = df[['food1','food2','food3']].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(sorted(set(x.dropna().astype(str)), reverse=False)), axis=1).values.tolist()

print(df)
```

result:

> ```
>     food1   food2    food3         food_all
> 0   apples  apples    mango    mango, apples
> 1  oranges  grapes  oranges  grapes, oranges
> 2  bananas  apples     None  bananas, apples
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It is working however, it is taking all the fields in the dataframe. I am just trying to merge just these three columns (food1, food2, food3) nothing else. I"ll update the data above

Answer (score 1):

You can get a set of row values with row-wise `apply`

```
df.apply(lambda x: list(set(x.dropna())), axis=1)
```

which outputs

```
0      [mango, apples]
1    [grapes, oranges]
2    [bananas, apples]
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

<s>You need to use `pd.concat` (or some other method) to create a non-unique list of each element in each DataFrame column.  Then you can pass the non-unique list to the `set` function.</s>

```
set(pd.concat([df['food 1'],df['food 2'],df['food 3']]))
```

#### EDIT

Sorry, I misunderstood your desired output the first time I read the question.  This will get you the desired output:

```
def get_set(row):
    return set([row['food 1'], row['food 2'], row['food 3']])

df['food_all'] = df.apply(get_set, axis=1)
```

This is because, as the error states, you can only pass hashable objects to a set.  As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14535730/what-do-you-mean-by-hashable-in-python), quoting [this source](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html), a set uses the hash value of an object internally, therefore any item passed to a set must be hashable.  Since the items in the list you are using to construct the set are `Series` objects, which aren't hashable, you cannot use that list to make the set.