# TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' from pandas' pd.factorize()

Tags: python, pandas, typeerror

So I'm following a tutorial on Multi-Class Text Classification and I'm trying to find a way to predict tags of on recipes in a supervised method with a JSON file that has the recipes in this format:

```
{
"title": "Turtle Cheesecake",
"summary": "Cheesecake is a staple at the Market, but it’s different nearly every day because we vary the toppings, crusts, and flavorings. Cookie crusts are particularly good with cheesecakes. If you prefer your cheesecake plain, just serve it without the topping",
"ingr": [
  "1½ cups graham cracker crumbs",
  "½ cup finely chopped pecans (pulse in a food processor several times)",
  "6 tablespoons ( ¾ stick) unsalted butter, melted",
  "1½ pounds cream cheese, softened",
  "¾ cup sugar",
  "2 tablespoons all purpose flour",
  "3 large eggs",
  "1large egg yolk",
  "½ cup heavy cream",
  "2 teaspoons pure vanilla extract",
  "1 cup sugar",
  "1 cup heavy cream",
  "½ teaspoon pure vanilla extract",
  "½ cup coarsely chopped pecans, toasted",
  "2 ounces semisweet chocolate, melted"
],
"prep": "To Make the Crust:\n\n\n\n Grease a 9-inch springform pan. Wrap the outside of the pan, including the bottom, with a large square of aluminum foil. Set aside.\n\n\n\..."
"tag": [
  "Moderate",
  "Casual Dinner Party",
  "Family Get-together",
  "Formal Dinner Party",
  "dessert",
  "dinner",
  "cake",
  "cheesecake",
  "dessert"
}
```

This is the code I'm running that's cause the TypeError:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_json('tagged-sample.json') 
######################### Data Exploration #######################

from io import StringIO

col = ['tag', 'summary']
df = df[col]
df = df[pd.notnull(df['summary'])]

df.columns = ['tag', 'summary']

df['category_id'] = df['tag'].factorize()[0]
```

What can I do to be able to use the pandas.factorize on the 'tag' category in 
the json. The tutorial does this on a csv file which might make a difference.
This is the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-d471748e6818> in <module>()
     12 df.columns = ['tag', 'summary']
     13 
---> 14 df['category_id'] = df['tag'].factorize()[0]
     15 
     16 #[['tag', 'category_id']].sort_values('category_id')

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py in factorize(self, sort, na_sentinel)
   1155     @Appender(algorithms._shared_docs['factorize'])
   1156     def factorize(self, sort=False, na_sentinel=-1):
-> 1157         return algorithms.factorize(self, sort=sort, na_sentinel=na_sentinel)
   1158 
   1159     _shared_docs['searchsorted'] = (

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    175                 else:
    176                     kwargs[new_arg_name] = new_arg_value
--> 177             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    178         return wrapper
    179     return _deprecate_kwarg

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\algorithms.py in factorize(values, sort, order, na_sentinel, size_hint)
    628                                            na_sentinel=na_sentinel,
    629                                            size_hint=size_hint,
--> 630                                            na_value=na_value)
    631 
    632     if sort and len(uniques) > 0:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\algorithms.py in _factorize_array(values, na_sentinel, size_hint, na_value)
    474     uniques = vec_klass()
    475     labels = table.get_labels(values, uniques, 0, na_sentinel,
--> 476                               na_value=na_value)
    477 
    478     labels = _ensure_platform_int(labels)

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_labels()

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Answer (score 3):

If you call `pd.factorize(s)`, where `s` is a Pandas Series, each element of the Series needs to be [hashable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14535730/7954504).

For example:

```
>>> s = pd.Series([1, 2, [3, 4, 5]])
>>> s
0            1
1            2
2    [3, 4, 5]
dtype: object
>>> pd.factorize(s)  # this will raise

>>> pd.factorize(s.drop(2))  # this is okay
(array([0, 1]), Int64Index([1, 2], dtype='int64'))
```

One way to workaround this (not sure what your end goal is) is to convert list elements to tuples, which are hashable:

```
>>> s.apply(lambda x: tuple(x) if isinstance(x, list) else x)
0            1
1            2
2    (3, 4, 5)
dtype: object

>>> pd.factorize(s.apply(lambda x: tuple(x) if isinstance(x, list) else x))
(array([0, 1, 2]), Index([1, 2, (3, 4, 5)], dtype='object'))
```

Comment: turns out just doing: df['category_id'] = df['tag'].apply(lambda x : pd.factorize(x)[0]) fixed the issue. Thanks for advise though.

Comment: Hm .. that's doing something markedly different, but whatever works for you