# Any quick way in Python to create and access a hashtable?

Tags: python, hashtable

I am trying to implement a LHS pattern match with a RHS action code in Python
How can I get a fast hashtable match.
Is this possible in Python? 
I need to fast match features in terms of x,y,c where x and y are coordinates and c is the color at index(x,y) of a 2d array.

Comment: Hashtable is called [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) in Python.

Comment: And check this answer to see which types can be hashed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44880799/937153

Answer (score 1):

An *hashmap* is a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) in python.

There are several ways to create dictionaries, here's 2:

```
d = dict(k=v)
```

or

```
d = {k:v}
```

---

To **get** the value of a key:

```
k = d.get("k")
```

or

```
k = d[k]
```

---

To **set** the value of a key:

```
d[k] = "ok"
```

---

Notes:

> In Python, dictionaries (or “dicts”, for short) are a central data
>   structure:
>
> Dicts store an arbitrary number of objects, each identified by a
>   unique dictionary key. Dictionaries are often also called maps,
>   hashmaps, lookup tables, or associative arrays. They allow the
>   efficient lookup, insertion, and deletion of any object associated
>   with a given key.

---

Resources:

1. [Dictionaries in Python](https://realpython.com/python-dicts/)
2. [Dictionaries, Maps, and Hash Tables in Python](https://dbader.org/blog/python-dictionaries-maps-and-hashtables)

Comment: A dictionary is a hashmap, not a hashtable. You can map values to hashable keys, but the keys are still just a set, not a table.

Answer (score 0):

The native type `dict` is a hashmap, not a hashtable, therefore you can only values to a key.

You can however simulate a hashtable by using `(x, y)` tuples as keys:

```
d = {}
d[(1,0)] = True
d[(1,1)] = False
```

This works because the `tuple` type in Python is hashable, meaning that as long as the values that it wraps are hashable, it can convert the value to a key.

Otherwise, you could extend the dict type to provide additional methods, letting you access values in a Java- or C-style 2D array:

```
d[1][0] = True
d[1][1] = False
```