# Comparing and switching key values in dictionaries

Tags: python

Suppose I have two dictionaries as such dict1 and dict2 and I wish to compare the keys of both dictionaries and if both are the same, plan on switching the value of the second dictionary to the key of the first dictionary. I came up with the following code:

```
dict1 = {"1|1":["xyx","zzz","zxz"],"1|2":["aa","xaa","bli"],"1|3":["jjj","kkk"]}

dict2 = {"1|1":{"hum1":"hum2"},"1|2":{"hum3":"hum4"},"1|4":{"hum5"}}

new_dict = {}

for k,v in dict1.items():
    for m,n in dict2.items():
        if(k==m):
            #new_dict[n] = v
            new_dict.update({n: v})
        
        
print(new_dict)




##new_dict = {{"hum1":"hum2"}:["xyx","zzz","zxz"],{"hum3":"hum4"}:["aa","xaa","bli"]}   expected output
```

I stumble upon the error: `unhashable type: 'dict'`

What might I be doing wrong here?

Comment: Your `new_dict` isn't valid Python, a dictionary like `{"hum1": "hum2"}` cannot be a dictionary key.

Comment: So , is there any alternative ?

Comment: You are using a value as a key. That value is a non-hashable type (as the error message says) which is okay for a value, but not for a key.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "hashable" mean in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14535730/what-does-hashable-mean-in-python)

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to achieve, so I don't know. Maybe a *tuple* `("hum1", "hum2")` as a key? How would you *use* the dictionary you're creating?

Comment: This sounds like an x-y problem. You literally can't do it like you said, but what did you actually want? Do you want to look up "hum1" and find ["xyx","zzz","zxz"]? What about hum2? Or is it more of a nested dict thing new_dict["hum1"]["hum2"] = ["xyx","zzz","zxz"] ? We can't tell what was intended.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a dict as a key, which is unhashable, You might use a Tuple, and here's compact version with `zip()` and `dict` comprehension:

```
new_list = {tuple(dict2[m].items()):dict1[k] for k,m in zip(dict1,dict2) if k==m}
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind the dictionary is that the keys are [hashable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) , meaning we apply some calculus to convert each key into a unique value. For that purpose, the key has to be immutable.

- **Hashable**: *string, int, float, tuple, bool*.
- **Unhashable**: *dict, list, set.*

You need to use a hashable type as key, for which you could transform `n` in `new_dict.update({n: v})`.

For example using: `str(n)` instead of `n`