# How can I zip list of list with a list into dictionary in python?

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary, zip

How can I zip list of list into dictionary in Python?

### Example

```
my_list_of_list =[[1,2,3],[0,2],[1,3]]
my list=[0,1,2]
```

### I want following output:

```
dictinoary={[0,1,2]:0 , [0,2]: 1 ,[1,3]:2}
```

I can do it with two list but I can not if one of them is list with more lists embedded.

Comment: That's not possible, as lists can't be dict keys.

Comment: why do you want to use list as key in dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

You cant use lists as keys in a dictionary since they are not [hashable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14535730/what-does-hashable-mean-in-python).

A workaround could be to cast the list keys from `my_list_of_list` into tuples:

```
>>> my_list_of_list = [[1, 2, 3], [0, 2], [1, 3]]
>>> my_list = [0, 1, 2]
>>> dictinoary = {tuple(k): v for k, v in zip(my_list_of_list, my_list)}
>>> dictinoary
{(1, 2, 3): 0, (0, 2): 1, (1, 3): 2}
```

Or alternatively into strings:

```
>>> dictinoary = {str(k): v for k, v in zip(my_list_of_list, my_list)}
>>> dictionary
{'[1, 2, 3]': 0, '[0, 2]': 1, '[1, 3]': 2}
```

Comment: GREAT !    Thank you very much . Appreciative you