# 'DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed with df as kwarg

Tags: python

I have this function:

```
def print_excel(path, filename, **kwargs):
    with pd.ExcelWriter(path + filename + timestr1 + '.xlsx') as writer:
        for df, sheet_name in kwargs.items():
            df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name, index=False)
```

And I also have this function call:

```
keywords = {df1: 'Sheet1', df2:'Sheet2'}
print_excel(path1, '_FileName.xlsx', **keywords)
```

However, when calling the function, it gives this error:

```
TypeError: 'DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

Why is this happening and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, most immutable python objects are hashable, while most mutable objects are not. An object has to be hashable for it to be used as a dictionary key — you can read more about what that means and why that's the case here: [What does "hashable" mean in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14535730/what-does-hashable-mean-in-python).

However, an object does *not* need to be hashable to be a dictionary *value*, so, in your case, a simple solution is just to swap the keys and values in your dictionary:

```
import pandas as pd

def print_excel(path, filename, sheet_dict):
    with pd.ExcelWriter(path + filename + timestr1 + '.xlsx') as writer:
        for sheet_name, df in sheet_dict.items():
            df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name, index=False)

sheets = {'Sheet1': df1, 'Sheet2': df2}
print_excel(path1, '_FileName.xlsx', sheets)
```

I took out the dictionary unpacking (the `**` notation) in your function signature, by the way, as it's entirely unnecessary for your function. In your case, the dictionary is just an input to your function. There's a related stack overflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters) on when to use `**` notation in function definitions, and a great tutorial [here](https://stackabuse.com/unpacking-in-python-beyond-parallel-assignment) on some of the really cool things you can do with tuple and dictionary unpacking in python.

Comment: No problem — glad I could help!