# TypeError: Unhashable type: 'set'/'list'

Tags: python

I am fairly new to programming and recently started working with dictionaries and a problem I am trying asks for me to create a list of names to take a poll. 2 names must not be in the dictionary while 2 more are in it.
The code:

```py
favorite_languages = {
    'jen': 'python',
    'sarah': 'c',
    'edward': 'ruby',
    'phil':  'python'
}
people = {'ryker', 'trey', 'jen', 'edward'}
for keys in favorite_languages:
    if people in favorite_languages:
        print(f"Thanks for taking our poll {people}")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In your own words, where the code says `if people in favorite_languages:`, what do you intend for that to do? Where it says `for keys in favorite_languages:`, what do you expect will be the value of `keys` each time through the loop?

Comment: "2 names must not be in the dictionary while 2 more are in it" - can you explain more clearly what you're trying to achieve exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if element exists in some List you use `in` operator, `elem in list`

```
print("1" in ["1", "2"]) # prints True
```

However `elem` need to be something [hashable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14535730/what-does-hashable-mean-in-python). For sure it cannot be set, but look here:

```
for keys in favorite_languages:
    if people in favorite_languages: # your elem = poeple (which is set)
        print(f"Thanks for taking our poll {people}")
```

You cannot check all people such way, you should check person one by one, so it would look that way

```
for person in people: # we iterate over all peoples one by one
    if person in favorite_languages:
        print(f"Thanks for taking our poll {person}")
```

Answer (score 0):

In this solution, I added the names common to both arrays to a list named poll_takers. This way, you only get those names printed in the end.

```
favorite_languages = {
    'jen': 'python',
    'sarah': 'c',
    'edward': 'ruby',
    'phil':  'python'
}
people = {'ryker', 'trey', 'jen', 'edward'}
poll_takers = []

for p in people:
    for keys in favorite_languages:
        if p in keys:
            poll_takers.append(p)
            print((f"Thanks for taking our poll {' '.join(poll_takers)}."))
```