# python: extract items of different lists and put them in one set

Tags: python, list, set

I have a file like this:

```
93.93.203.11|["['vmit.it', 'umbertominnella.it', 'studioguizzardi.it', 'telestreet.it', 'maurominnella.com']"]
168.144.9.16|["['iipmalumni.com','webdesignhostingindia.com', 'iipmstudents.in', 'iipmclubs.in']"]
195.211.72.88|["['tcmpraktijk-jingshen.nl', 'ellen-siemer.nl'']"]
129.35.210.118|["['israelinnovation.co.il', 'watec-peru.com', 'bsacimeeting.org', 'wsava2015.com', 'picsmeeting.com']"]
```

I want to extract domains in all the lists and add them to one set. ultimately, i would like to have a fine with each unique domain in one line. Here is the code I have written:

```
set_d = set()
f = open(file,'r')
for line in f:
    line = line.strip('\n')
    ip,list = line.split('|')
    l = json.loads(list)
    for e in l:
        domain = e.split(',')
        set_d.add(domain)
        print set_d
```

but it gives the below error:

```
    set_d.add(domain)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Can anybody help me out?

Comment: Maybe this is helpful:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306631/python-add-list-to-set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use str.translate to clean the text and add to the set using update:

```
set_d = set()
with open(file,'r') as f:
    for line in f:
       lst = (x.strip() for x in line.split("|")[1].translate(None,"\"'[]").split(","
        set_d.update(lst)
```

outputs a unique set of individual domains:

```
set(['vmit.it', 'tcmpraktijk-jingshen.nl', 'umbertominnella.it', 'studioguizzardi.it', 'telestreet.it', 'watec-peru.com', 'bsacimeeting.org', 'webdesignhostingindia.com', 'wsava2015.com', 'iipmstudents.in', 'maurominnella.com', 'ellen-siemer.nl', 'picsmeeting.com', 'iipmalumni.com', 'iipmclubs.in', 'israelinnovation.co.il'])
```

which you can write to  a new file:

```
set_d = set()
with open(file,'r') as f,open("out.txt","w") as out:
    for line in f:
        lst = (x.strip() for x in line.split("|")[1].translate(None,"\"'[]").split(","))
        set_d.update(lst)
    for line in set_d:
        out.write("{}\n".format(line))
```

The output:

```
$ cat out.txt 
vmit.it
tcmpraktijk-jingshen.nl
umbertominnella.it
studioguizzardi.it
telestreet.it
watec-peru.com
bsacimeeting.org
webdesignhostingindia.com
wsava2015.com
iipmstudents.in
maurominnella.com
ellen-siemer.nl
picsmeeting.com
iipmalumni.com
iipmclubs.in
israelinnovation.co.il
```

Your code will not separate into individual domains, your json call does not really do anything to help. Changing your code to update will output something like the following:

```
{" 'maurominnella.com']", " 'wsava2015.com'", "'webdesignhostingindia.com'", " 'iipmclubs.in']", " 'ellen-siemer.nl'']", " 'umbertominnella.it'", " 'picsmeeting.com']", "['israelinnovation.co.il'", "['vmit.it'", " 'iipmstudents.in'", "['tcmpraktijk-jingshen.nl'", " 'studioguizzardi.it'", "['iipmalumni.com'", " 'watec-peru.com'", " 'bsacimeeting.org'", " 'telestreet.it'"}
```

Also don't use list as a variable name either it shadows the python `list`

Answer (score 1):

You should call `update` instead of `add`;

```
set_d.update(domain)
```

Example;

```
>>> set_d = {'a', 'b', 'c'}
>>> set_d.update(['c', 'd', 'e'])
>>> print set_d
{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the result of `split` function is a list (`domain = e.split(',')`)and lists are unhashable you cant add them to [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#module-sets) . instead you can add those elements to your set with [`set.update()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#module-sets) , But you dont need `Json` as it doesn't separate your domain and doesn't give you the desire result instead you can use `ast.literal_eval` to split your list :

```
import ast
set_d = set()
f = open(file,'r')
for line in f:
    line = line.strip('\n')
    ip,li = line.split('|')
    l = ast.literal_eval(ast.literal_eval(li)[0])
    for e in l:
        domain = e.split(',')
        set_d.update(domain)
    print set_d
```

Note that dont use of python built-in functions or types as your variable!

And as a more efficient way you just can use regex to grub your domains :

```
f = open(file,'r').read()
import re
print set(re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z\-]+\.[a-zA-Z]+',f))
```

result:

```
set(['vmit.it', 'tcmpraktijk-jingshen.nl', 'umbertominnella.it', 'studioguizzardi.it', 'telestreet.it', 'israelinnovation.co', 'bsacimeeting.org', 'webdesignhostingindia.com', 'iipmstudents.in', 'maurominnella.com', 'ellen-siemer.nl', 'picsmeeting.com', 'watec-peru.com', 'iipmalumni.com', 'iipmclubs.in'])
[Finished in 0.0s]
```

Comment: Thanks Kasra. How can I get read of the json object notation, "u"?

Comment: @Mee You need to encode to ascii , check out the edit

Comment: @PadraicCunningham i just resolve the OP's current issue ! if OP have another problem that tell about that i will remove those too! also i add another way with regex

Comment: @PadraicCunningham whats the problem with ignore ? OP just want to remove `u`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham OK, fixed!

Comment: @PadraicCunningham i use 2 time of literal _eval at first i choose the first element of list that is a string list!!! then convert to list again!also i think literal_eval is for this purpose and is more efficient