# While removing the duplicates i got this unhasable type: 'list' error !!!TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Tags: python, list, duplicates

```
data_keys=list(set(data_keys))
print data_keys
```

I tried to remove the duplicate keys in this list and i found this error.

i am looking for simple solution for this.

Error Message:

```
data_keys=list(set(data_keys))
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: You should show what `data_keys` is.

Comment: Evidently `data_keys` contains lists, which cannot be placed in a set. Or used as keys in a dictionary, for that matter.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are having item of [`list`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list) type in your `data_list`. [`set()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-set) can be only used with hashable objects, and list is not hashable. For example:

```
>>> data_list = [1, 2, 3]   # All numbers, works fine
>>> set(data_list)
{1, 2, 3}


>>> data_list = [1, 2, 3, [1, 2, 3]]   # Has `list` as an element
>>> set(data_list)                     # Raises `TypeError`
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

In order to make this work, you can convert the nested list to [`tuple`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#tuple) as:

```
>>> data_list = [1, 2, 3, (1, 2, 3)]
#                          ^  It is `tuple` instead of `list`
>>> set(data_list)       # works fine
{1, 2, 3, (1, 2, 3)}
```

For more information, you may read: [*Otto's Answer to "Python: Add list to set?"*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1306653/2063361)

Comment: so what will be the solution.  i have a long list so viewing it is a difficult task

Comment: I already added at the end of my answer. Use `tuple` instead of `list` as elements to `data_list`

Comment: and to convert your big list into a tuple use `tuple(your_list)` so it would be: `data_keys=list(set(tuple(data_keys)))`