# Leetcode 90. TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

i'm reciving the following error in my program: unhashable type: 'list'.
I want to eliminate duplicate elements from the list, but failed.
Here is the code:

```py
class Solution:
    def subsetsWithDup(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:
        result = []
        ele_num = len(nums)
        sub_size = 2 ** ele_num
        for i in range(sub_size):
            result.append([])
        for i in range(ele_num):
            for j in range(sub_size):
                if j >> i & 1:
                    result[j].append(nums[i])
        s = list(set(result)) 
        return s
```

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: You just wish to return a list without duplicates?

Comment: Yes, I also tried to convert it to a set and then convert back to a list, but I get the same error .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
class Solution:
    def subsetsWithDup(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:
        result = []
        ele_num = len(nums)
        sub_size = 2 ** ele_num
        for i in range(sub_size):
            result.append([])
        for i in range(ele_num):
            for j in range(sub_size):
                if j >> i & 1:
                    result[j].append(nums[i])

        s = set(tuple(arr) for arr in result)
        result_without_duplicates = [list(tupl) for tupl in s]
        return result_without_duplicates

s = Solution()
print(s.subsetsWithDup([1, 1, 1]))
```

---

Why you were getting that error? Sets can not contain mutable objects. Lists are mutable. Read more about it in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306631/python-add-list-to-set).

The simplest example which will give the same error is:

```
my_list = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
print(set(my_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way to remove duplicates from a list is to convert it to a set (a collection of unique elements) and then convert back to a list

```
def subsetsWithDup(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[int]:
    return list(set(nums))
```

Comment: unhashable  type : 'list'.

Comment: I was completely confused

Comment: `nums` is not a list of integers then? It's a list of lists?

Comment: Yes, it's a list of lists.

Comment: And what do you want to return? A list of all unique ints?