# Is there a significant overhead by using different versions of sha hashing (hashlib module)

Tags: python, hash, hashlib

The [`hashlib`](http://docs.python.org/library/hashlib.html) Python module provides the following hash algorithms constructors: `md5()`, `sha1()`, `sha224()`, `sha256()`, `sha384()`, and `sha512()`.

Assuming I don't want to use md5, is there a big difference in using, say, sha1 instead of sha512? I want to use something like `hashlib.shaXXX(hashString).hexdigest()`, but as it's just for caching, I'm not sure I need the (eventual) extra overhead of 512...

Does this overhead exist, and if so, how big is it?

Comment: If it is for caching, why do you need a secure hash?

Comment: When you tried the different methods and measured their performance, what did you find?

Comment: What @GregHewgill probably meant to say is that there is a convenient standard library module `timeit` which makes such measurements so trivial that it's easier to just time it than to ask about it, especially when it's run from the command line.

Comment: @GregS what would you use instead of a secure hash? I need to have a fingerprint of a python dict (containing search parameters) so that I can determine (1) if this search has already been done before and (2, if it's a new search) if the results of the search are available for display.

Comment: I defer to sttwister. Since I learned something from the exchange, I'm upvoting the question.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Why not just benchmark it?

```
>>> def sha1(s):
...     return hashlib.sha1(s).hexdigest()
...
>>> def sha512(s):
...     return hashlib.sha512(s).hexdigest()
...
>>> t1 = timeit.Timer("sha1('asdf' * 100)", "from __main__ import sha1")
>>> t512 = timeit.Timer("sha512('asdf' * 100)", "from __main__ import sha512")
>>> t1.timeit()
3.2463729381561279
>>> t512.timeit()
6.5079669952392578
```

So on my machine, `hash512` is twice as slow as `sha1`. But as [GregS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/238704/gregs) said, why would you use secure hash for caching? Try the builtin hash algorithms which should be really fast and tuned:

```
>>> s = "asdf"
>>> hash(s)
-618826466
>>> s = "xxx"
>>> hash(s)
943435
>>> hash("xxx")
943435
```

Or better yet, use the builtin Python dictionaries. Maybe you can tell us more about what you plan on caching.

*EDIT:*
I'm thinking that you are trying to achieve something like this:

```
hash = hashlib.sha1(object_to_cache_as_string).hexdigest()
cache[hash] = object_to_cache
```

What I was refferring to by "use the builtin Python dictinoaries" is that you can simplify the above:

```
cache[object_to_cache_as_string] = object_to_cache
```

In this way, Python takes care of the hashing so you don't have to!

Regarding your particular problem, you could refer to [Python hashable dicts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151658/python-hashable-dicts) in order to make a dictionary hashable. Then, all you'd need to do to cache the object is:

```
cache[object_to_cache] = object_to_cache
```

**EDIT - Notes about Python3**

Python 3.3 introduces hash randomization, which means that computed hashes might be different across different processes, so you should not rely on the computed hash, unless setting the `PYTHONHASHSEED` environment variable to 0.

References:
 - [https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.**hash**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__)
 - https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONHASHSEED

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to benchmark it. As many of you said, I probably don't need to use secure hashing for caching.

Basically I need to store a fingerprint of [the content of] a dictionary. As I can't use either `hashlib` or `hash()` directly on a dictionary, I was building a string containing the elements of that dictionary (don't like this approach) and then use `hashlib` on it... But now you've intrigued me with "use the builtin Python dictionaries", what do you mean by that?

Comment: By reading your comments (all of you), I realized I didn't need to use any secure hashing, so I implemented my own "hashing" algorithm. Since the dictionnary always have specific elements, and each value has an idea, I create a string from those ideas and cache that. Thanks all.

Comment: To any looking at this answer's recommendation to use hash() instead of hashlib for non-crypto hashing: keep in mind that in Python 3 and some implementations of Python 2, `hash()` does not return consistent values across different instances and so may be problematic if you're running on a distributed platform and trying to generate cache keys or something like that.  For example, every "dyno" (like a linux instance) on Heroku appears to return a different result for `hash()` on the same string. Its only consistent inside the instance itself. GAE reportedly has similar behavior.

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps a naive test... but it looks like it depends on how much you're hashing. 2 blocks of sha512 is faster than 4 blocks of sha256?

```
>>> import timeit
>>> import hashlib
>>> for sha in [ x for x in dir(hashlib) if x.startswith('sha') ]:
...   t = timeit.Timer("hashlib.%s(data).hexdigest()" % sha,"import hashlib; data=open('/dev/urandom','r').read(1024)")
...   print sha + "\t" + repr(t.timeit(1000))
...
sha1    0.0084478855133056641
sha224  0.034898042678833008
sha256  0.034902095794677734
sha384  0.01980900764465332
sha512  0.019846916198730469
```

Comment: I got similar results.  I think the de facto learning here is that md5 and sha1 are similar in speed (I also benchmarked md5 using this method) and then sha512 is faster than all the hashes in between.  Therefore, use sha1 for speed and sha512 for better hashing.  The others don't make sense from a performance point of view.

Comment: I got very different results, maybe the current implementation or machines are better optimized :    
`sha1`  : `0.00902104377746582`
`sha224`  : `0.007354021072387695` 
`sha256`  : `0.007508993148803711` `sha384`  : `0.004772186279296875` `sha512`  : `0.004884004592895508`