# Cast base class to derived class python (or more pythonic way of extending classes)

Tags: python, inheritance, derived-class, base-class

I need to extend the Networkx python package and add a few methods to the `Graph` class for my particular need

The way I thought about doing this is simplying deriving a new class say `NewGraph`, and adding the required methods.

However there are several other functions in networkx which create and return `Graph` objects (e.g. generate a random graph).  I now need to turn these `Graph` objects into `NewGraph` objects so that I can use my new methods.

What is the best way of doing this?  Or should I be tackling the problem in a completely different manner?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

If you are just adding behavior, and not depending on additional instance values, you can assign to the object's `__class__`:

```
from math import pi

class Circle(object):
    def __init__(self, radius):
        self.radius = radius

    def area(self):
        return pi * self.radius**2

class CirclePlus(Circle):
    def diameter(self):
        return self.radius*2

    def circumference(self):
        return self.radius*2*pi

c = Circle(10)
print c.radius
print c.area()
print repr(c)

c.__class__ = CirclePlus
print c.diameter()
print c.circumference()
print repr(c)
```

Prints:

```
10
314.159265359
<__main__.Circle object at 0x00A0E270>
20
62.8318530718
<__main__.CirclePlus object at 0x00A0E270>
```

This is as close to a "cast" as you can get in Python, and like casting in C, it is not to be done without giving the matter some thought.  I've posted a fairly limited example, but if you can stay within the constraints (just add behavior, no new instance vars), then this might help address your problem.

Comment: Ok, so what happens when you _do_ need to add variables?

Comment: You can add/set instance variables at runtime. Careful though that you don't get confused with instance variable that are added by a CirclePlus __init__  that you forgot to add because this casting method bypasses __init__ I suppose? By the way, since Python's type system can be overridden, this casting method will not always work.

Comment: If you find that you need to add instance variables too, then I think you are quickly getting beyond the realm of maintainable code - time to rethink your design, probably using some form of containment and/or delegation.

Answer (score 17):

Here's how to "magically" replace a class in a module with a custom-made subclass without touching the module. It's only a few extra lines from a normal subclassing procedure, and therefore gives you (almost) all the power and flexibility of subclassing as a bonus. For instance this allows you to add new attributes, if you wish.

```
import networkx as nx

class NewGraph(nx.Graph):
    def __getattribute__(self, attr):
        "This is just to show off, not needed"
        print "getattribute %s" % (attr,)
        return nx.Graph.__getattribute__(self, attr)

    def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
        "More showing off."
        print "    setattr %s = %r" % (attr, value)
        return nx.Graph.__setattr__(self, attr, value)

    def plot(self):
        "A convenience method"
        import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
        nx.draw(self)
        plt.show()
```

So far this is exactly like normal subclassing. Now we need to hook this subclass into the `networkx` module so that all instantiation of `nx.Graph` results in a `NewGraph` object instead. Here's what normally happens when you instantiate an `nx.Graph` object with `nx.Graph()`

```
1. nx.Graph.__new__(nx.Graph) is called
2. If the returned object is a subclass of nx.Graph, 
   __init__ is called on the object
3. The object is returned as the instance
```

We will replace `nx.Graph.__new__` and make it return `NewGraph` instead. In it, we call the `__new__` method of `object` instead of the `__new__` method of `NewGraph`, because the latter is just another way of calling the method we're replacing, and would therefore result in endless recursion.

```
def __new__(cls):
    if cls == nx.Graph:
        return object.__new__(NewGraph)
    return object.__new__(cls)

# We substitute the __new__ method of the nx.Graph class
# with our own.     
nx.Graph.__new__ = staticmethod(__new__)

# Test if it works
graph = nx.generators.random_graphs.fast_gnp_random_graph(7, 0.6)
graph.plot()
```

In most cases this is all you need to know, but there is one gotcha. Our overriding of the `__new__` method only affects `nx.Graph`, not its subclasses. For example, if you call `nx.gn_graph`, which returns an instance of `nx.DiGraph`, it will have none of our fancy extensions. You need to subclass each of the subclasses of `nx.Graph` that you wish to work with and add your required methods and attributes. Using [mix-ins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533631/what-is-a-mixin-and-why-are-they-useful) may make it easier to consistently extend the subclasses while obeying the [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) principle.

Though this example may seem straightforward enough, this method of hooking into a module is hard to generalize in a way that covers all the little problems that may crop up. I believe it's easier to just tailor it to the problem at hand. For instance, if the class you're hooking into defines its own custom `__new__` method, you need to store it before replacing it, and call this method instead of `object.__new__`.

Comment: Can I do this with a built-in? If for example, I want to cast `set` to `SpecialSet` can I change the built-in's `__new__` behavior?

Comment: @GrantJ That won't work. Most python builtins are implemented in C, and as such are not as malleable as pure python classes. You'll get this error: `TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'set'`.

Comment: `def __new__(cls):` should also accept more arguments. They are not used in the creation, but will be passed on to the instantiation --> `def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):`

Answer (score 4):

I expanded what PaulMcG did and made it a factory pattern.

```
class A:
 def __init__(self, variable):
    self.a = 10
    self.a_variable = variable

 def do_something(self):
    print("do something A")


class B(A):

 def __init__(self, variable=None):
    super().__init__(variable)
    self.b = 15

 @classmethod
 def from_A(cls, a: A):
    # Create new b_obj
    b_obj = cls()
    # Copy all values of A to B
    # It does not have any problem since they have common template
    for key, value in a.__dict__.items():
        b_obj.__dict__[key] = value
    return b_obj

if __name__ == "__main__":
 a = A(variable="something")
 b = B.from_A(a=a)
 print(a.__dict__)
 print(b.__dict__)
 b.do_something()
 print(type(b))
```

Result:

```
{'a': 10, 'a_variable': 'something'}
{'a': 10, 'a_variable': 'something', 'b': 15}
do something A
<class '__main__.B'>
```

Comment: This is an awesome generic way to cast an object of a parent class to a child class.  Especially useful for complex objects that need slight alterations.  Worked great for me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could simply create a new `NewGraph` derived from `Graph` object and have the `__init__` function include something like `self.__dict__.update(vars(incoming_graph))` as the first line, before you define your own properties. In this way you basically copy all the properties from the `Graph` you have onto a new object, derived from `Graph`, but with your special sauce.

```
class NewGraph(Graph):
  def __init__(self, incoming_graph):
    self.__dict__.update(vars(incoming_graph))

    # rest of my __init__ code, including properties and such
```

Usage:

```
graph = function_that_returns_graph()
new_graph = NewGraph(graph)
cool_result = function_that_takes_new_graph(new_graph)
```

Comment: Mostly in the right direction, but I would also advise the asker to look for specifically what APIs their class provides for this. In the asker's example, a look at the [`Graph` class documentation](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/graph.html#networkx.Graph) suggests that your subclass could do `self.add_edges_from(original_graph)`. Or as another answer suggests, it looks like their `__init__` already provides copy-construction (as a well-designed library class `__init__` should, in most cases).

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same question when contributing to `networkx`, because I need many new methods for `Graph`. The [answer by @Aric](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4718855/10181743) is the simplest solution, but inheritance is not used. Here a native `networkx` feature is utilise, and it should be more efficient.

There is [a section in `networkx` tutorial, using the graph constructors](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/tutorial.html#using-the-graph-constructors), showing how to init `Graph` object from existing objects for a graph, especially, another graph object. This is the example shown there, you can init a new `DiGraph` object, `H`, out of an existing `Graph` object, `G`:

```py
>>> G = Graph()
>>> G.add_edge(1, 2)
>>> H = nx.DiGraph(G)   # create a DiGraph using the connections from G
>>> list(H.edges())
[(1, 2), (2, 1)]
```

Note the mathematical meaning when converting an existing graph to a directed graph. You can probably realise this feature via some function or constructor, but I see it as an important feature in `networkx`. Haven't checked their implementation, but I guess it's more efficient.

To preserve this feature in `NewGraph` class, you should make it able to take an existing object as argument in `__init__`, for example:

```py
from typing import Optional
import networkx as nx


class NewGraph(nx.Graph):

    def __init__(self, g: Optional[nx.Graph] = None):
        """Init an empty directed graph or from an existing graph.

        Args:
            g: an existing graph.
        """
        if not g:
            super().__init__()
        else:
            super().__init__(g)
```

Then whenever you have a `Graph` object, you can **init** (NOT turn it directly to) a `NewGraph` object by:

```
>>> G = nx.some_function()
...
>>> NG = NewGraph(G)
```

or you can init an empty `NewGraph` object:

```
>>> NG_2 = NewGraph()
```

For the same reason, you can init another `Graph` object out of `NG`:

```py
>>> G_2 = nx.Graph(NG)
```

Most likely, there are many operations after `super().__init__()` when initiating a `NewGraph` object, so the [answer by @PaulMcG](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3464154/10181743), as he/she mentioned, is not a good idea in such circumstance.

Comment: *This* is the right answer. Our first approach in these situations should be to check if the class you are subclassing already supports copy-construction or provides a method to copy data from one instance or another (in this case, it provides both), and use that if available.

Answer (score 0):

If a function is creating Graph objects, you can't turn them into NewGraph objects.

Another option is for NewGraph is to have a Graph rather than being a Graph.  You delegate the Graph methods to the Graph object you have, and you can wrap any Graph object into a new NewGraph object:

```
class NewGraph:
    def __init__(self, graph):
        self.graph = graph

    def some_graph_method(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.graph.some_graph_method(*args, **kwargs)
    #.. do this for the other Graph methods you need

    def my_newgraph_method(self):
        ....
```

Comment: Thanks

I read somewhere else that I can just change the __class__ attribute. e.g. MyRandomGraphObject.__class__ = NewGraph.  And it does actually work.  Bad practice?

Answer (score 0):

For your simple case you could also write your subclass `__init__` like this and assign the pointers from the Graph data structures to your subclass data.

```
from networkx import Graph

class MyGraph(Graph):
    def __init__(self, graph=None, **attr):
        if graph is not None:
            self.graph = graph.graph   # graph attributes
            self.node = graph.node   # node attributes
            self.adj = graph.adj     # adjacency dict
        else:
            self.graph = {}   # empty graph attr dict
            self.node = {}    # empty node attr dict 
            self.adj = {}     # empty adjacency dict

        self.edge = self.adj # alias 
        self.graph.update(attr) # update any command line attributes


if __name__=='__main__':
    import networkx as nx
    R=nx.gnp_random_graph(10,0.4)
    G=MyGraph(R)
```

You could also use copy() or deepcopy() in the assignments but if you are doing that you might as well use

```
G=MyGraph()
G.add_nodes_from(R)
G.add_edges_from(R.edges())
```

to load your graph data.

Comment: This worked for me. But how to do it with double-underscore methods?

Answer (score 0):

The `__class__` assignment approach actually alters the variable. If you only want to call a function form the super class you can use `super`. For example:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def f(self):
        print("A")

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    def f(self):
        print("B")

b = B()
b.f()
super(type(b), b).f()
```

is returning

```
B
A
```

Answer (score -3):

Have you guys tried 
[[Python] cast base class to derived class](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=877526)

I have tested it, and seems it works. Also I think this method is bit better than below one since below one does not execute **init** function of derived function.

```
c.__class__ = CirclePlus
```