# Python: How do I promote an object from a base class to a derived class?

Tags: python

Hope this isn't too basic, but...

Suppose I have a base class *pa()*, and I have derived classes *pai()*, *paj()*, etc, that inherit from the base class.

I would like to instantiate an object from base class *pa()*:

```
>>> from pamod import *
>>> mypa = pa()
>>> mypa
<pamod.pa object at 0x28d4fd0>
>>>
```

... and then promote it (cast it) to a derived class, based on some action:

```
>>> mypa.do(this)  
>>> mypa
<pamod.pai object at 0x28d4fd0>
>>>
```

Where based on the value of "this", *mypa* becomes an object from class *pai*, etc.

I know I can assign to the object's `__class__`.

> > > mypa.`__class__` = pai

However I'm wondering if that's really the best approach.

Under my scheme, each instance of *pai* (say) would have started life as an instance of the base class *pa*, so *pai*'s `__init__` method could be overloaded somehow, I'm guessing.

See
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464061/cast-base-class-to-derived-class-python-or-more-pythonic-way-of-extending-classe)
discussion.

Peter

Answer (score 4):

It's a terrible approach, since you have to handle initialization of the new attributes yourself. Write a class method in the child that returns a new instance with the appropriate attributes copied over.

Comment: Or write your `__init__` so it optionally accepts an instance of the base class.

Comment: +1 DIP is your friend http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle

Comment: It would be a good way of monkey patching an object to add methods. `1.` Derive the class of the object and add some methods. `2.` Promote  the object

Answer (score 0):

I don't get it. Seems like reassigning `__class__` keeps me from having to copy everything over, which is good since we're talking a huge (100's of MiB) amount of data.

(I'm answering my own question here so I can include code)

What's wrong with this? In reality, "x" and "y" might represent some vast amount of data. Calling mypa.do(1) promotes mypa to a member of class pai:

```
class pa(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1.0

    def do(self,i):
        if i==1:
            self.__class__ = pai
            self.promote()

class pai(pa):
    def __init__(self):
        pa.__init__(self)
        self.promote()

    def promote(self):
        self.y = 2.0
```