# The Pythonic way of validating a long chain of conditions in Python

Tags: python

So I have a long chain of conditions that should be validated to be true. Instead of chaining a long `if` condition, I tried to be "innovative" and did it this way, which I reckon is more readable. But my question is, is this the optimal way of doing it?

Or is there a pythonic way of doing it? PS: Please respond with an alternative instead of answering "No", thanks!

Here's the code chunk:

```
def site_exists(site):
    """
    returns the sitebean if it exists,
    else returns false
    """
    vpadmin_service = _get_vpadmin_service(site)
    all_sites = VpAdminServiceUtil.getSites(vpadmin_service)
    for site_listing in all_sites:
        if site.getId():
            #condition check
            try:
                assert site.getId() == site_listing.getId()
                assert site.getName() == site_listing.getName()
                assert site.getCustomer().getId() == site_listing.getCustomer().getId()
            except AssertionError:
                continue
            #pass conditions
            return site_listing
        #no id, so just check for name and customer
        else:
            #condition check
            try:
                assert site.getName() == site_listing.getName()
                assert site.getCustomer().getId() == site_listing.getCustomer().getId()
            except AssertionError:
                continue
            #pass conditions
            site.setId(site_listing.getId())
            return site_listing
    return False
```

Comment: in case one is wondering about the camel cases, its because i'm mixing some java methods in it. am using jython.

Comment: Using assert and try-except might be performance hit. However, it's really minor thing, unless you have really huge number of sites.

Comment: @Olli: nope. performance is not an issue here. would you suggest a better way of parsing a long chain of conditions instead thats readable and less performance inpeding?

Comment: Why do you test site.getId each time through the loop? Should that be `if site_listing.getId()`?

Comment: @michael: there is an else clause that i did not include in the code chunk. EDIT: just revised the code chunk to incl everything.

Comment: @nubela I guess I see the point, now. In the end, that's not very relevant, though -- it's just about the string of assertions, and we don't need to worry about side effects in the tests.

Comment: Note that the `assert` statement won't be executed if python is not run in debug mode. See http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.6/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-assert-statement

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using exception for control flow is bad! And it will also kill your performance. Assuming the condition will be true in one out of 10 cases? So 9 exceptions to handle in the worst case - this comes with a huge performance cost.

If you want readability, try:

```
        if (
            condition1 and \
            condition2 and \
            condition3
            ):
            # do something
```

For the revised version, this should be equivalent:

```
for site_listing in all_sites:
    if site.getName() == site_listing.getName() and site.getCustomer().getId() == site_listing.getCustomer().getId():
        if not site.getId():
            site.setId(site_listing.getId())
        if site.getId() == site_listing.getId():
            return site_listing
```

Comment: What are you talking about? I use exceptions for control flow all the time. And it'll jump to the `except` clause on the first exception thrown, so there's no efficiency issue.

Comment: Sorry, forgot that, I added how I would do it.

Comment: There's no need to use backslashes when the code is inside parentheses.

Comment: @Thiefmaster: true, but it helps my eyes ;-)

Comment: Sebastian, you're probably german. But "contition" should be written "condition" ;-)

Comment: Indeed, but everybody produces typos? Fixed.

Comment: @Sebastian Blask: `'\'` at EOL is ugly especially when it is not necessary.

Answer (score 10):

A simpler approach is to build a tuple of the conditions and compare the tuples:

```
def site_info(s):
    return s.getId(), s.getName(), s.getCustomer().getId()

if site_info(site) == site_info(site_listing):
    return site_listing
else:
    continue
```

If you have a lot of conditions, or the conditions are expensive, you can instead create a generator for the conditions, and compare with `any` or `all`:

```
import itertools
def iter_site_info(s):
    yield s.getId()
    yield s.getName()
    yield s.getCustomer().getId()

if all(x==y for (x, y) in itertools.izip(iter_site_info(site), iter_site_info(site_listing)):
    return site_listing
else:
    continue
```

I'm not sure whether Jython has `any` and `all`, but they're trivial functions to write.

EDIT - `any` and `all` appeared in Python 2.5, so Jython should have them.

Comment: building a tuple of results may be less efficient since it will not short circuit - the functions getId, getName, getCustomer().getId will all be called every time, but with the other methods here functions after the first failure will be skipped.

Comment: @Dave Kirby Yes, building the tuple does unnecessary work, which is why the generator version is there. Either way, it should be split off into a function, and a generator is a natural way to handle any expensive computations.

Answer (score 3):

I would implement an `is_same` method on `site` and call it in the `for` loops.

```
all_sites = VpAdminServiceUtil.getSites(vpadmin_service)
for site_listing in all_sites:
    if site_listing.is_same(site, set_id=True):
        return site_listing
```

As for its implementation (that is your real question), I suggest something like:

```
...
if self.getName()     != site.getName():     return False
if self.getCustomer() != site.getCustomer(): return False
...
return True
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `__eq__` method! If you wrote the class of `site` yourself, no problem. If it is from a module outside of your control, see [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464061/cast-base-class-to-derived-class-python-or-more-pythonic-way-of-extending-classe/4714744#4714744), or create a somewhat less elegant wrapping class. For the wrap variant, this would be the class:

```
class WrappedSite(object):
    def __init__(self, site):
        self.site = site

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if site.getId():
            if self.site.getId() != other.site.getId():
                return False
        if self.site.getName() != other.site.getName():
            return False
        if self.site.getCustomer().getId() != other.site.getCustomer().getId():
            return False
        return True
```

Then your big ugly function is reduced to this:

```
def site_exists(site):
    """
    returns the sitebean if it exists,
    else returns false
    """
    vpadmin_service = _get_vpadmin_service(site)
    all_sites = VpAdminServiceUtil.getSites(vpadmin_service)
    wsite = WrappedSite(site)
    for site_listing in all_sites:
        if wsite == WrappedSite(site_listing):
            return site_listing
    return False
```

**EDIT** Fixed `site_exists` to return sitebean instead of True.

Comment: You should really only provide your own implementation of __eq__ if there is a single, universally understood meaning of 'equality' for the given object. If you violate this rule, you risk encountering very strange behaviour.

Comment: @Simon Good advice. I leave it to the poster to determine if this is a problem, as I'm not familiar with these `site` objects. To remedy the problem, if it is one, turn the `__eq__` method into a function `sites_are_the_same` (drop the wrapping class) and do `if sites_are_the_same(site, site_listing):` instead in the [antepenultimate](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/antepenultimate) line of `site_exists`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove some code duplication:

```
def site_exists(site):
    """
    returns the sitebean if it exists,
    else returns None
    """
    vpadmin_service = _get_vpadmin_service(site)
    all_sites = VpAdminServiceUtil.getSites(vpadmin_service)

    for site_listing in all_sites:
        if (site.getName() == site_listing.getName() and
            site.getCustomer().getId() == site_listing.getCustomer().getId()):
            if site.getId(): # if id is set; it should be the same
                if site.getId() != site_listing.getId(): continue
            else: # no id; consider it the same site
                site.setId(site_listing.getId()) #XXX side-effect
            return site_listing
```

Note: it is unexpected that `site_exists()` might modify its argument (via `.setId()`). Consider to refactor it:

```
def same_site(site, other):
    if site.getId() and site.getId() != other.getId(): 
       # if id is set; it should be the same
       return False 
    return (site.getName() == other.getName() and
            site.getCustomer().getId() == other.getCustomer().getId())

def get_site_listing(site):
    """
    returns the sitebean corresponding to `site`,
    returns None if there is none
    """
    vpadmin_service = _get_vpadmin_service(site)
    all_sites = VpAdminServiceUtil.getSites(vpadmin_service)

    return next((s for s in all_sites if same_site(site, s)), None)
```

Note: the code doesn't modify the `site` object. Use the return value from `get_site_listing()` instead.

If `next()` is unavailable then use:

```
for site_listing in all_sites:
    if same_site(site, site_listing):
       return site_listing
return None
```

btw, `jython` should provide [`property`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property) wrappers for you; so you could write:

```
def same_site(site, other):
    if site.id and site.id != other.id: 
       # if id is set; it should be the same
       return False 
    return site.name == other.name and site.customer.id == other.customer.id
```

and `site.id = id` instead of `site.setId(id)`.

Answer (score 0):

Using an exception handler as a code target is basically a "goto".  I don't see anything wrong with it really (despite the ancient furor surrounding "goto considered harmful"), but knowing that it's a goto might give you a different perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Using exception handling for control flow is pythonic in the sense that "it's easier to ask for forgiveness than for permission". However, that doesn't extend to making rules to break just so that you can ask for forgiveness.

Others have provided excellent alternatives. Just wanted to address the principle aspect.