# How to extend an existing python instance

Tags: python

I'm trying to wrap my brain around something here... Let's say that I have a simple setup of class inheritance:

```
class SuperClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.var = 1

class SubClass(SuperClass):
    def getVar(self):
        return self.var
```

If I have an existing instance of `SuperClass`, is there a way that I can 'cast' it as `SubClass`, without creating a new instance?

Comment: Looks like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3464154) may be what I'm looking for...

Comment: I think this is one of those ... just because you can doesnt mean you should...  I would look at the Factory Design Pattern and instantiate it later, once you know what you want ..

Comment: Why do you want to? What are you hoping to accomplish? Why isn't `getVar` a `SuperClass` method?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: That was just a very simple example, that's not actually my code.

Comment: Well, yes; the point is that a proper solution to your problem depends on the details of your actual situation - because this isn't the sort of thing you want to solve with a general-purpose brute-force approach that tackles the issue the way you propose to. Wanting to do this sort of thing very frequently points to a design flaw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python you don't have a `cast` operator - you can get around this by assigning the type to the instance's `__class__` attribute:

```
>>> super_instance = SuperClass()
>>> super_instance.__class__ = SubClass
>>> print super_instance.getVar()
1
```

However, this is more error prone than `cast` in many other languages as the validity and safety of your "`cast`" is not verified by the compiler.

For example, if `SubClass` had a method that accessed an attribute that was not available on `SuperClass` then attempting to call that method on `super_instance` would result in an error at run time, even though it *appears* to be a valid instance of `SubClass`.

Comment: I'm not even sure I know what I'm really trying to do anymore- I'm trying to create a state machine to mimic some hardware.  Need to give this some more thought... Your answer is correct, it works fine. But I agree that I should rethink what the heck I'm doing.

Comment: Don't use subtype to indicate the state in a state machine; use the internal state of the object (i.e., attributes). Even if you need different behaviour, you may find life much easier using the State/Strategy pattern.