# Instantiate children class from parent without changing parent code

Tags: python, class, inheritance, instantiation

First of all, here is my (pseudo) code:

> somemodule.py:

```
class parentclass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        if(not prevent_infinite_reursion) #Just to make shure this is not a problem ;)
            self.somefunction()

    def somefunction():

        # ... deep down in a function ...

        # I want to "monkey patch" to call constructor of childclass, 
        # not parentclass
        parentclass()
```

> othermodule.py

```
from somemodule import parentclass

class childclass(parentclass):
    def __init__(self):
        # ... some preprocessing ...

        super(childclass, self).__init__()
```

The problem is, i want to monkey patch parent class, so it would call constructor of **childclass**, without changing code of **somemodule.py**.
It doesn't matter if it's patched only in class instance(that's shure better) or globally.

I know i can override **somefunction**, but it contains too many lines of code, for this being sane.

**Thanks!**

Comment: You want _all_ attempts to construct a `parentclass` to instead construct a `childclass`, or only attempts within `parentclass`, or only this specific attempt within `parentclass.somefunction`, or one of the latter two but only when `self` is a `childclass`?

Comment: Well any of this, so i will appreciate any kind of answer, but the best would be attempts in parentclass.

Comment: Actually, that's probably the most difficult possibility. But let me think about it…

Comment: I covered this in [my very first answer on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4714744/566644), though it replaces *all* occurances of `parentclass()`.

Comment: @LauritzV.Thaulow: Yes, hooking `__new__` is fine for hooking all attempts to construct a `parentclass`, but it won't hook only attempts within `parenclass` itself, which is what the OP said would be best. Can you think of a way to do that?

Comment: I can think of two horribly hacky things that might work: (1) Replace each method of `parentclass` with a wrapper that patches out `__new__`, calls the original, and restores `__new__`. (2) Replace each method of `parentclass` with a wrapper that runs the original inside a modified `globals` where `parentclass` has been replaced by `childclass`. But I don't think either of these is a good enough idea to be worth coding.

Comment: @abarnert well i think i could do it, because currently i have to patch only one function, will try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [mock.patch](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/patch.html#patch) for this:

```
class childclass(parentclass):
    def somefunction(self):
        with patch('somemodule.parentclass', childclass):
            super(childclass, self).somefunction()
```

Comment: A nice clean way to do my "horribly hacky thing (1)".

Comment: Hm it doesn't work in my case, because parentclass is eventually a children of some other class and parent of parentclass __new__ method gets called and it creates parentclass instead of supposedly patched child class, will try to find how to manage that.

Comment: @offlinehacker You can patch the `__new__` method as well. Also it might help to read [where to patch](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/patch.html#id1).

Comment: @LauritzV.Thaulow eventually it worked like a charm with patching `__new__` of a top class. This one was hard. Thanks!