# How do I modify class method without touching source code in python?

Tags: python, methods, patch

How do I modify class method without touching source code?

There's a class from a library which I don't want to change the source code of.

```
class SomeLibraryClass(object):
  def foo(self, a_var):
     print self, a_var, "hello world"
```

Now, I want to define my own `foo` method, and substitute for the original `SomeLibraryClass.foo` .

```
def foo(obj, a_var):
   print obj, a_var, "good bye"

SomeLibraryClass.foo = foo //
```

What should I do with the **self** variable?
How can I do this?

Comment: It'll work, just use self as first parameter in your own code for clarity.

Comment: If you want other methods and functions in that library to return your modified class, take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4714744/566644).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same thing as you would do with `self` if you were in a method. `self` will be passed as the first parameter to your function and will be a reference to the current object. So if you want to define a function that will be used as a replacement for a method, just add self as the first parameter.

```
class SomeLibraryClass(object):
  def __init__(self, x):
      self.x = x

  def foo(self, y):
     print('Hello', self.x, y)

def my_foo(self, y):
    print ('Good buy', self.x, y)

SomeLibraryClass.foo = my_foo
```

And how to use it:

```
>>> s = SomeLibraryClass(33)
>>> s.foo(5)
Good buy 33 5
```