# How to convert a `TextBuffer` to `GtkSourceBuffer`?

Tags: python, casting, gtk, pygtk

In python I need to convert `TextBuffer` into `GtkSourceBuffer`. How Do I achieve this ?

Comment: I guess you mean `GtkTextBuffer`, right?

Comment: Yes that's what I means.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cast base class to derived class python (or more pythonic way of extending classes)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464061/cast-base-class-to-derived-class-python-or-more-pythonic-way-of-extending-class)

Comment: the actual question is: what are you trying to achieve? a `SourceBuffer` is a `TextBuffer`, so you can pass any instance of the former to any method or signal of the latter. you cannot do the opposite, obviously, or you'd be violating the substitution principle of the type system.

Answer (score 0):

You could just do

```
txtbuf.__class__ = GtkSourceBuffer
```

which should work as long as `txtbuf` actually **is** an instance of type `GtkSourceBuffer`.