# Why is __new__ a staticmethod and not a classmethod?

Tags: python

According to [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__),

> `__new__()` is a static method (special-cased so you need not declare
>   it as such) that takes the class of which an instance was requested as
>   its first argument.

It explicitly *isn't* a classmethod, but generally looks like one, except that any client manually calling `__new__` needs to do explicitly pass in the class argument. For example:

```
>>> str.__new__()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    str.__new__()
TypeError: str.__new__(): not enough arguments
>>> str.__new__(str)
''
```

But alternate object creation APIs - eg, [all eight alternate `datetime` constructors](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime) - *are* usually `classmethod`s, so that `datetime.now()` works as expected.

Why is `__new__` set up this way?

Comment: Maybe because not being a classmethod allows you to do something like `BaseClass.__new__(DerivedClass)`.

Comment: It can be useful in metaclasses or when we override an immutable object, because in those cases we call it using: `type.__new__(meta, ...)` and `float.__new__(NewFloat, ...)`

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary but the only time you would use that is inside `NewFloat.__new__`, where `super().__new__(...)` would do the right thing. Also, why would that logic not apply to overridden alternate constructors?

Comment: I think i've understood: two different class "arguments" would not be needed if Python could [cast instances of a base class into instances of a derived class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3464061).  If it was possible, then, after calling the ancestor class' `__new__` from the descendant class' `__new__`, one could cast the returned instance into the descendant type.  As this seems impossible (in an unhackish way), the ancestor's `__new__` should be able to return the descendant's instance.

Comment: It seems weird that it is not a class method, though.  Is it mildly prohibited to use from `__new__` the class where it is defined?