# Casting an instance to a derived class which has extra data members

Tags: python, inheritance, casting

This question is very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464061/cast-base-class-to-derived-class-python-or-more-pythonic-way-of-extending-class), but my derived class has extra data members. Consider the two classes below. I need to convert instances of `Circle` objects into instances of `ColoredCircle`. In my real, less simplistic application, I would prefer to avoid re-initializing thousands of these objects, making sure I call the derived class constructor correctly with the base instance members and whatnot.

```
class Circle(object):
    def __init__(self, radius):
        self.radius = radius
    def area(self):
        return pi * self.radius**2
    def __str__(self):
        return 'Circle: %f' % self.radius

class ColoredCircle(Circle):
    def __init__(self, radius, color):
        super(ColoredCircle, self).__init__(radius)
        self.color = color
    def __str__(self):
        return 'ColoredCircle: %f %s' % (self.radius, self.color)
    def getColor(self):
        return self.color
```

It seems that if I have a `Circle` instance `c`, I can change its `__class__` to `ColoredCircle`, and once I also set `c.color`, then everything seems to work as if I had instanced it with `ColoredCircle` to begin with.

Questions:

1. Are there any major pitfalls or other reasons it would be a bad idea to do something like the following to cast an instance of a base class into an instance of the derived class?
2. Is there a better way to do this?

```
c = Circle(3)
print c                     # Circle: 3.000000
print c.area()              # 28.274333882308138
c.__class__ = ColoredCircle
print c.area()              # still works
print c.getColor()          # AttributeError: 'ColoredCircle' object has no attribute 'color'
c.color = 'blue'
print c                     # ColoredCircle: 3.000000 blue
```

Comment: Question 0 should be: Why would you want to do this? Unless you can provide a reason, I'm closing this question as hypothetical.

Comment: @200_success This is definitely not hypothetical as it is something I ran into at work. I have a function that gives me a collection of instances of a base type, and later I need to cast to the derived type so I can use functionality of that type.

Comment: Could you explain why you're instantiating the wrong kind of circle then?

Comment: @200_success I actually hadn't really considered that. In my particular case, I think I can get away with this. I would accept "instantiate the right kind of Circle" as the answer to my second question.

Answer (score 3):

> (1) are there any major pitfalls or other reasons it would be a bad idea to do something like the following to cast an instance of a base class into an instance of the derived class?

This is a dirty dirty dirty hack, and the violation of all that's good and sacred in this world. Kittens will perish in masses.

This is a blatant violation of encapsulation. It only works with intimate knowledge of the derived class. Why rewrite the DNA of an object in a dirty way when you can create a clean object easily using a constructor.

If you fully know all the details of the target object 100%, then sure, this works, but it's a very dirty hack. If this is for a one time correction or something, you can probably get away with it, otherwise it will become a maintenance nightmare, as if some day something changes in the target class, you will have to update the hack.

> (2) Is there a better way to do this?

Yes, use the constructor to create objects of a different type. It's really not clear why you're reluctant to walk this obvious path.

Comment: `Yes, use the constructor to create objects of a different type.` How can I do this (more) cleanly? My actual base class has ~dozen data members. If I do `cc = ColoredCircle(c.data0, c.data1, <...>, c.data10)`, then pass most of those to the `Circle` super constructor from the `ColoredCircle` constructor, that seems at least as error prone and unmaintainable. Furthermore, `Circle` has internal data that is not settable through its constructor; I would have to expose those members in both constructors, violating encapsulation even worse. All this is why I am reluctant to go down this path.

Comment: Your question didn't mention that there are so many members. Keep in mind that having such high number of members is a huge warning sign about the design. We're off to a very bad start here. But even so, passing a dozen members to the constructor is still safer and less error-prone, because tools can help you detect problems, such as incorrect number of constructor arguments. If you go down the other path, you're on your own, tools can't help, and the risk of discovering obscure bugs only at runtime is higher

Comment: @SchighSchagh if the problem is lots of constructor arguments, then abstract a collection to hold them.