# Swift Replacing/Redefining Method or Class of Library

Tags: swift, class, replace, ios-charts

I'm searching quite a while now but I cannot find anything. Is there a possibility in Swift to supply an own implementation of a class or a method without touching the library. Subclassing would not be an option.

As Example from ios charts (https://github.com/danielgindi/ios-charts) I only want to replace the LineScatterCandleRadarChartRenderer class (https://github.com/danielgindi/ios-charts/blob/master/Charts/Classes/Renderers/LineScatterCandleRadarChartRenderer.swift) or the single method it is implementing. It is a subclass of a subclass of a subclass used somewhere in the library when plotting the chart.

What would be the best practice to do this?

I found an answer for python: [Cast base class to derived class python (or more pythonic way of extending classes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464061/cast-base-class-to-derived-class-python-or-more-pythonic-way-of-extending-class/4714744#4714744)

Comment: Why is subclassing not an option?

Comment: I would have to subclass quite many classes until I come to a point where I can use one of them in my code.

Comment: If you understand OOP, such demand cannot be fulfilled unless you subclass or touch the library. That's the whole OOP meaning.