# How to transform a base-class object into a sub-class object?

Tags: python, class, inheritance

In my project, I'm creating a base_class object first, but later on the program it should become a subclass. In the example, first I created an `animal`, later I've decided that it should become a `dog`. In this case, I don't wanna delete my old `animal` object and create a new dog object which may have `super()` function in it, because I don't want to pass all `animal` creation arguments all over again.

So is there any better method other than shown in the example to code something like this.

```py
class animal:
    def __init__(self, H):
        self.hight =  H
        print("animal created @ height : ", self.hight)

x = animal(10)
#animal created @ height :  10

class dog: #with cheap trick
    def __init__(self, animal_object,  color):
        self.animal_object = animal_object
        self.color = color
        print("animal became a dog")
        print("dog's @ color : ", self.color)
        print("dog's @ heigth : ", self.animal_object.hight)

y = dog(x, "black") #animal becomes a dog

# animal became a dog
# dog's @ color :  black
# dog's @ heigth :  10


class tranform_to_dog(animal): #super() method
    def __init__(self, H, color):
        super().__init__(H)
        self.color = color
        print("Dog created as a subclass of animal, heigth: {}, color:{}".format(self.hight,self.color))

z = tranform_to_dog(8, "white")
#Dog created as a subclass of animal, heigth: 8, color:white
```

Above, I want to keep going with `X` object which is already created as an `animal` and call `tranform_to_dog` method with X so I can get `z` like subclassed object

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cast base class to derived class python (or more pythonic way of extending classes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464061/cast-base-class-to-derived-class-python-or-more-pythonic-way-of-extending-class)

Comment: But, `x.__class__ =tranform_to_dog`  does not run `tranform_to_dog` 's `__init__` function. Skipping this  may cause a dog with no fur!!

Answer (score 0):

Still, there is a hard mapping for variables but might be solved with `@classmethod` :

```py
class animal:
    def __init__(self, H):
        self.hight =  H
        print("animal created @ height : ", self.hight)

x = animal(10)
#animal created @ height :  10

class tranform_to_dog(animal): #super() method
    def __init__(self, H, color):
        super().__init__(H)
        self.color = color
        print("Dog created as a subclass of animal, heigth: {}, color:{}".format(self.hight,self.color))

    @classmethod
    def from_animal(cls, animal_object, color):
        return cls(animal_object.hight, color)


w = tranform_to_dog.from_animal(x, "yellow")
#Dog created as a subclass of animal, heigth: 10, color:yellow
```