# Python dictionary keys besides strings and integers?

Tags: python, dictionary

Anyone have some neat examples of dictionaries with some interesting keys (besides the canonical string or integer), and how you used these in your program?

I understand all we need for a key is something `hashable`, meaning it must be immutable and comparable (has an `__eq__()` or `__cmp__()` method).

A related question is: how can I quickly and slickly define a new `hashable`?

Comment: `hashable` == you can call it's `__hash__` method and get an int. Nothing more. Comparision functions would be needed if dicts/sets/etc were e.g. binary trees.

Comment: I seem to have been misled by this definition: http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-hashable

Comment: @delnan: hashable in the context of Python also means comparable -- look at the link Pete posted.  But it does not include immutable.

Comment: I stand correct. And now that you mention it, it's indeed necessary (since dicts use comparision for for collision detection).

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Let's go for something a bit more esoteric. Suppose you wanted to execute a list of functions and store the result of each. For each function that raised an exception, you want to record the exception, and you also want to keep a count of how many times each kind of exception is raised.  Functions and exceptions can be used as `dict` keys, so this is easy:

```
funclist = [foo, bar, baz, quux]

results    = {}
badfuncs   = {}
errorcount = {}

for f in funclist:
    try:
        results[f] = f()
    except Exception as e:
        badfuncs[f]   = e
        errorcount[type(e)] = errorcount[type(e)] + 1 if type(e) in errorcount else 1
```

Now you can do `if foo in badfuncs` to test whether that function raised an exception (or `if foo in results` to see if it ran properly), `if ValueError in errorcount` to see if any function raised `ValueError`, and so on.

Comment: Neat, great example which seems like a great way to organize analysis results in memory.  fix typo errorcount[t]-->errorcount[f]. Counting doesn't seem to work, not sure why it shouldn't when I iterate over the functions again without reinitializing the dict.

Comment: Actually, that was supposed to be `type(e)` rather than `t` as this dictionary should be counting the number of times each exception type was raised. I initially had a line in there that said `t = type(e)` which is where the `t` came from. Anyway, fixed. :-)

Answer (score 18):

You can use a tuple as a key, for example if you want to create a multi-column index.  Here's a simple example:

```
>>> index = {("John", "Smith", "1972/01/01"): 123, ("Bob", "Smith", "1972/01/02"): 124}
>>> index
{('Bob', 'Smith', '1972/01/02'): 124, ('John', 'Smith', '1972/01/01'): 123}
>>> index.keys()
[('Bob', 'Smith', '1972/01/02'), ('John', 'Smith', '1972/01/01')]
>>> index['John', 'Smith', '1972/01/01']
123
```

For an example of how to use a dict as a key (a hashable dict) see this answer:
[Python hashable dicts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151658/python-hashable-dicts)

Comment: Note that you can omit the tuple parens, thus having a big code readability improvement (`index['John', 'Smith', '1972/01/01']`)

Answer (score 16):

You left out the probably most important method for an object to be [hashable](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-hashable): `__hash__()`.

The shortest implementation of your own hashable type is this:

```
class A(object):
    pass
```

Now you can use instances of `A` as dictionary keys:

```
d = {}
a = A()
b = A()
d[a] = 7
d[b] = 8
```

This is because user-defined classes are hashable by default, and their hash value is their id -- so they will only compare equal if they are the same object.

Note that instances of `A` are by no means immutable, and they can be used as dictionary keys nevertheless.  The statement that dictionary keys must be immutable only holds for the built-in types.

Comment: Being mutable and hashable at the same time is *allowed*, but it's usually insane.

Comment: Many kinds of Python objects are technically mutable, but are still hashable. If it were "insane", why would user-created objects be that way by default?

Comment: @kindall: I don't quite understand why `object.__hash__` behaves like this (as objects using it don't work as expected as dictionary keys). But see http://wiki.python.org/moin/DictionaryKeys for why it's one giant headache.

Comment: Did not know user-defined classes are hashable by default... thanks for your answer

Answer (score 6):

Note that I've never really used this, but I've always thought using tuples as keys could let you do some interesting things. I would find it a convenient way to map grid coordinates, for example. You can think of this like a grid on a video game (maybe some kind of tactics game like [Fire Emblem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fire_Emblem)):

```
>>> Terrain = { (1,3):"Forest", (1,5):"Water", (3,4):"Land" }
>>> print Terrain
{(1, 5): 'Water', (1, 3): 'Forest', (3, 4): 'Land'}
>>> print Terrain[(1,3)]
Forest
>>> print Terrain[(1,5)]
Water
>>> x = 3
>>> y = 4
>>> print Terrain[(x,y)]
Land
```

Something like that.

Edit: As Mark Rushakof pointed out in the comments, I'm basically intending this to be a [sparse array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_array).

Comment: Yes - tuples as keys are great.  I have used them to store results of data sorted into bins.

Comment: I think everyone in one's right mind would just use a two-dimensional array to store the terrain types of the map :)

Comment: @Sven Marnach: I actually kind of like the tuples since it's a little more straightforward to skip over spaces (i.e. leave them blank).

Comment: @eldarerathis and @Sven: Yes, a tuple-dictionary like this is very well-suited for [sparse arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_array).

Comment: @Mark Rushakof: Yes, precisely! I knew there was a special name for that and couldn't for the life of me remember it. Thanks!

Comment: @Mark, @eldarerathis: Doing a PhD in numerical mathematics, I am more than familiar with the concept of two-dimensional sparse arrays and I know its a useful concept.  My point is that the map in Fire Emblem is *not* sparse, and using this data structure for a dense array is not a good idea.  No offense intended :)

Comment: @Sven Marnach: None taken. I don't think I see why this *couldn't* be a sparse array, though. Taking Fire Emblem as a specific example, if we consider a map where maybe 90% or so of the tiles have no def/avoid modifiers (not unreasonable in FE), then it seems intuitive to me to use a sparse array. The default tile type (maybe "Land" is actually best for this) could be used for any tiles that are not defined in the dictionary, I would think, and you would save some memory. Or I'm completely missing the point here, maybe.

Comment: Indeed, you can even use collections.defaultdict to return the default value if an undefined key is used.

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea why you'd want to do it (and preferably, please **don't** do it)... but alongside strings and integers, you can also use both simultaneously. That is, as a beginner, I found it both powerful and surprising that:

```
foo = { 1:'this', 2:'that', 'more':'other', 'less':'etc' }
```

is an entirely valid dictionary, which provides access to `foo[2]` as easily as it does to `foo['more']`.

Comment: This comes up when using Django in my experience. Querysets often come back with integers (e.g. ID values) for keys and they look like this when cast to dicts for JSON representation. I agree it should be avoided if possible.