# Why aren't Python sets hashable?

Tags: python, hash, set

I stumbled across a blog post detailing how to implement a powerset function in Python. So I went about trying my own way of doing it, and discovered that Python apparently cannot have a set of sets, since set is not hashable. This is irksome, since the definition of a powerset is that it is a set of sets, and I wanted to implement it using actual set operations.

```
>>> set([ set() ])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'
```

Is there a good reason Python sets are not hashable?

Comment: Anything that isn't immutable generally makes for a bad key. You can use tuples if you have to.

Answer (score 169, accepted):

Generally, only immutable objects are hashable in Python.  The immutable variant of [`set()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) -- [`frozenset()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset) -- is hashable.

Comment: And see the Python FAQ entry [Why must dictionary keys be immutable?](http://docs.python.org/3.3/faq/design.html#why-must-dictionary-keys-be-immutable).

Answer (score 36):

Because they're mutable.

If they were hashable, a hash could silently become "invalid", and that would pretty much make hashing pointless.

Answer (score 21):

From the Python docs:

> **hashable**
>    An object is hashable if it
>   has a hash value which never changes
>   during its lifetime (it needs a
>   **hash**() method), and can be compared to other objects (it needs an
>   **eq**() or **cmp**() method). Hashable objects which compare equal
>   must have the same hash value.
>
> Hashability makes an object usable as
>   a dictionary key and a set member,
>   because these data structures use the
>   hash value internally.
>
> All of Python’s immutable built-in
>   objects are hashable, while no mutable
>   containers (such as lists or
>   dictionaries) are. Objects which are
>   instances of user-defined classes are
>   hashable by default; they all compare
>   unequal, and their hash value is their
>   id().

Answer (score 7):

In case this helps... if you really need to convert unhashable things into hashable equivalents for some reason you might do something like this:

```
from collections import Hashable, MutableSet, MutableSequence, MutableMapping

def make_hashdict(value):
    """
    Inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151658/python-hashable-dicts
     - with the added bonus that it inherits from the dict type of value
       so OrderedDict's maintain their order and other subclasses of dict() maintain their attributes
    """
    map_type = type(value)

    class HashableDict(map_type):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(HashableDict, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        def __hash__(self):
            return hash(tuple(sorted(self.items())))

    hashDict = HashableDict(value)

    return hashDict


def make_hashable(value):
    if not isinstance(value, Hashable):
        if isinstance(value, MutableSet):
            value = frozenset(value)
        elif isinstance(value, MutableSequence):
            value = tuple(value)
        elif isinstance(value, MutableMapping):
            value = make_hashdict(value)

        return value

my_set = set()
my_set.add(make_hashable(['a', 'list']))
my_set.add(make_hashable({'a': 1, 'dict': 2}))
my_set.add(make_hashable({'a', 'new', 'set'}))

print my_set
```

My HashableDict implementation is the simplest and least rigorous example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151658/python-hashable-dicts).  If you need a more advanced HashableDict that supports pickling and other things, check the many other implementations.  In my version above I wanted to preserve the original dict class, thus preserving the order of OrderedDicts.  I also use AttrDict from [here](https://github.com/mk-fg/layered-yaml-attrdict-config) for attribute-like access.

My example above is not in any way authoritative, just my solution to a similar problem where I needed to store some things in a set and needed to "hashify" them first.

Comment: Due to the `sorted`, this requires an order on the values. There are objects which define `__eq__` and `__hash__` but not an order (`__le__` etc). You could use `hash(frozenzet(self.items()))` instead.