# Set operations without using data type Set()

Tags: python, list, set

**Problem:**

Here's a list as an input `[A,B,C,E]`

**Output:**

```
[A,B]
[A,C]
[A,E]
[B,C]
[B,E]
[C,E]
```

Basically, I want to take the union of the list with itself.

Here's the **code**:

```
pageSet_list = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'E']

pageSet_set = list() # To create a list of sets so that we can take their union

for page in pageSet_list:
    toBeAdded = set(page)
    pageSet_set.append(toBeAdded)
pageSet_list = list()

for i in range(len(pageSet_set)):
    for j in range(i,len(pageSet_set)):
        z=pageSet_set[i].union(pageSet_set[j])
        if (len(z) == 2): # somethin = set([])
            print 'z: ',z
            pageSet_list.append(z)
```

**Output of this code:**

```
z:  set(['A', 'B'])
z:  set(['A', 'C'])
z:  set(['A', 'E'])
z:  set(['C', 'B'])
z:  set(['B', 'E'])
z:  set(['C', 'E'])
```

**Error:**

```
z:  set(['C', 'B'])
```

Output should have been `z:  set(['B', 'C'])`.

Now recently, I got to know that set is an an unordered data structure and therefore it does not maintain any particular order of the elements. Performing union operation of two sets, by using `union` method, changes the order of elements.

**My question is:**

How do I perform the set operations, union and intersection, without using data type set()?

Comment: perhaps look into the [NumPy library](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/index.html)?

Comment: is the order re-creatable? could you just sort the data later on to re-establish its order? and how is order maintained through, say, intersection? if have `(1, 2, 3)` and `(3, 2)`, what's the result?

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini I have edited the question. No, it is not a duplicate.

Comment: @acushner I have edited the question. Please take a look.

Comment: So you want [combinations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)? I don't see why sets need to be involved here

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini Can this be done using lists and some simple logic?

Comment: And i am going through the documentation link which you have provided @AndreaCorbellini

Comment: Try `list(itertools.combinations(['A', 'B', 'C', 'E'], 2))`

Comment: Okay it's working for input [A,B,C,E] @Robᵩ How to make this work for list [['A', 'B'], ['A', 'C'], ['A', 'E']] ?
So that I get output : [[A,B,C], [A,B,E], [A,C,E]] (combinations of length 3)

Comment: Basically what you want is **not** taking the union of the list with itself (and has nothing to do with the `set` datatype). You're just finding all the combinations of pairs—in other words, two at a time—of the elements of a list.

Comment: I'm agreeing with the duplicate here; if you just enter `set(['B', 'C'])` into the interpreter, it will reverse the order to `set(['C', 'B'])`.

Comment: This post is linked from [Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339191/can-existing-users-be-friendly-here-to-newcomers-who-ask-genuine-questions) (10k+ link) so it may have additional downvotes on top of mismatch between what is asked (set operations) with what is expected (probably caresian product which produces ordered pairs and not sets)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import itertools

for acom in itertools.combinations('ABCD',2):
    print acom
```

Comment: Okay it's working for input [A,B,C,E] . How to make this work for list [['A', 'B'], ['A', 'C'], ['A', 'E']] ? So that I get output : [[A,B,C], [A,B,E], [A,C,E]] (combinations of length 3)

Comment: for acom in itertools.combinations(['AB', 'AC', 'AE'] ,2): print sorted(set(acom[0] + acom[1]))

Comment: for acom in combinations(['AB', 'AC', 'AE','BC','BE','CE'] ,2): print sorted(set(acom[0] + acom[1])) How to get rid of the duplicates?

Comment: print map(list,list(set([''.join(sorted(set(acom[0] + acom[1]))) for acom in itertools.combinations(['AB','AC','AE','BC','BE','CE'],2)])))

Comment: If you untangle that pythonic mumbo jumbo, it goes as following: first you get a list of combinations as strings, then remove duplicates by converting it into set, then convert it into list again, and finally dismantle strings into lists: list('ABC') is ['A','B','C'].

Comment: yy = set()
for acom in combinations(['AB', 'AC', 'AE','BC','BE','CE'] ,2): yy.add(set(acom[0] + acom[1]))
@organis
I tried converting it to a list but i am getting an error:  TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'

Comment: Set elements must be hashable (simply put, can be used as dictionary keys: numbers, strings, booleans). This thread explains that nicely: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6310867/why-arent-python-sets-hashable

Comment: This thread helped a lot. thanks, @Organis