# Eliminate duplicate from list of lists

Tags: python, list, duplicates, set

I need to eliminate duplicates from a list of list like this one:

```
    list = [[10, 5, 3], [10, 5, 3], [10, 10, 3], [10, 10], [3, 3, 3], [10, 5, 3]]
```

As a expected result:

```
    result_list = [[10, 5, 3], [10, 3], [10], [3]]
```

Eliminating duplicates inside sub-lists and in the main list, would it be possible?
I tried with:

```
    result_list = [list(result) for result in set(set(item) for item in list)]
```

but throws an TypeError saying that a set is a unhashable type

I think it was not a duplicated question, i need to remove the duplicates within the sublists, not just in the main list.
Thanks to everyone who helped me, problem solved.

Comment: Does order need to be preserved? What should happen to `[10, 3, 10]`?

Comment: maybe this is helpful https://www.w3resource.com/python-exercises/list/python-data-type-list-exercise-69.php

Comment: no need to preserve the order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `map` in order to convert to `tuple`

```
result = [list(set(i)) for i in set(map(tuple, mylist))]
```

Output

```
[[3], [10, 3, 5], [10, 3], [10]]
```

Comment: Thanks, really elegant solution.

Comment: @delete, then you Could accept the answer in order to help other people

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know how to do it, done now.

Answer (score 1):

Sets aren't hashable, but frozensets are:

```
lst = [[10, 5, 3], [10, 5, 3], [10, 10, 3], [10, 10], [3, 3, 3], [10, 5, 3]]
result_list = [list(result) for result in set(frozenset(item) for item in lst)]
```

Also don't shadow the builtin name `list`, especially if you want to use its usual meaning immediately after.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `tuples` to be able to `set`, however in a nested list comprehension, you can turn this tuple items back to lists:

```
list_example = [[10, 5, 3], [10, 5, 3], [10, 10, 3], [10, 10], [3, 3, 3], [10, 5, 3]]
output = [list(x) for x in (list(set([tuple(set(result)) for result in list(set(item) for item in list_example)])))]
print(output)
```

Output:

```
[[10, 3, 5], [10], [10, 3], [3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating a list:

`for item in list`

putting the results into a set:

`set(item)`

then putting the set into a set:

`set(set(item)`

For anything to go into a `set` it has to be hashable, meaning it has a defined hash value resulting from being an immutable object. `set`s aren't immutable, and so don't have a hash. See [Why aren't Python sets hashable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6310867/why-arent-python-sets-hashable).