# How to compare two list of sets effectively in python?

Tags: python, list, set, unique

I have a list of sets:

```
list = [{1,2}, {2,3}, {1,3}, {2,1} etc]
```

I need a list where every element appears once.
creating a set of the list fails with a set is not hashable error
If I create another list, and add every element once with if not in list then append list works,
but now I have to deal with a list with aroun 600 000 value pairs, and it takes forever.
Is there a more efficent way?

Comment: What about using `set(map(tuple, list_))`?

Comment: it fails with map() must have at least two arguments.
if i add another empty list, it returns an empty list

Comment: Given the answer by @AntoineDubuis - can you please clarify the desired output.  My my understanding of 'unique element' refers to a set of `{1, 2}` - whereas the answer provided returns unique individual values.

Comment: well, since these are sets, from list = [{1,2}, {2,3}, {1,3}, {2,1}]
I need one of the {1,2} elements removed
I need only the unique pairs, without directions or position
so the output would be: result_list = [{1,2}, {2,3}, {1,3}]

Comment: It has two elements, `tuple` and your list.  I used `list_` as your variable `list` is overwriting the built-in.

Comment: @biohazard90 Do you need output as a list that contains unique "sets" or unique "single values"? Meaning, for a set `{1, 2}` is the same as `{2, 1}`, so considering your input, is your output supposed to be `{1, 2, 3}` or `[{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {1, 3}]`?

Comment: @ChatterOne A list that contains unique "sets"
I think what S3DEV suggested actually worked, but if you have another solution feel free to share

Comment: You can use `set(map(frozenset, data))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referencing your comment; as you mentioned this worked, I'll post my comment as a proper answer.

```
set(map(tuple, list_))
```

Output:

```
{(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)}
```

Please note:
I've changed the your `list` variable named to `list_`, as it was overwriting the built-in.

This method appears to scale linearly. Time over a list of 1000 sets was 206 us and 10000 was 2.19 ms.

Comment: If i understand this correctly:
the problem is that sets are not hashable. 
To get around the problem, we use the map function, which creates a tuple of every single sets, thus it will be hashable (since the set becomes an immutable tuple) and then it can be passed into the set function right?

Comment: Yep. [This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6310901/6340496), which quotes the docs, clarifies it nicely.  Glad it's working for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following method to perform a union on a list of set:

```
l = [{1,2}, {2,3}, {1,3}, {2,1}]
set.union(*l)
```

output:

```
{1, 2, 3}
```