# TypeError: unhashable type: 'set' in Flask Form

Tags: python, forms, flask, form-submit

I am trying to fetch data from form in Flask:

**app.py**

```
@app.route('/newProjectCreation/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def newProjectCreation():
    try:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            # Data Fetch from Models Form
            name = request.form['modelName']
            modelDescription = request.form['modelDescription']
            inputType = request.form.getlist['inputType[]']
            outputType = request.form.getlist['outputType[]']
            model = request.files['model']
            modelLanguage = request.form['modelLanguage']
```

**HTML**

It is a simple form (not Flask-WTF form) and the fields "*inputType*" and "*outputType*" are supposed to return array as they are [dynamically input fields](https://tutorial101.blogspot.com/2021/01/python-flask-add-remove-input-fields.html).

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/adiagarwal/cad/flaskapp-docker/flaskapp/app.py", line 106, in newProjectCreation
    inputType = request.form.getlist['inputType[]']
TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/adiagarwal/cad/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2464, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/adiagarwal/cad/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/home/adiagarwal/cad/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/adiagarwal/cad/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/adiagarwal/cad/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/adiagarwal/cad/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/adiagarwal/cad/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/adiagarwal/cad/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/adiagarwal/cad/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/adiagarwal/cad/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/adiagarwal/cad/flaskapp-docker/flaskapp/app.py", line 129, in newProjectCreation
    return {{e}}
TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'
```

*I don't have prior experience in js and I am learning, if possible please simplify the response.*

Thank You in advance.

Comment: You are trying to use `set` as key in a dict in Python. A `set` can not be used as hashable value.

Comment: So, what should I do instead? Actually, I did not understand your reply.
Please guide

Comment: Please share the full error, to exactly where error raises. Also, check what a `set` is in Python and whether they are hasable or not.

Comment: according to this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6310867/why-arent-python-sets-hashable : sets are not-hashable, sets being mutable they are not hashable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I was focused on a big problem, but the problem is so simple that I did not realize it: Replace all `[]` with `()`. See below.

If you `[]` it assumes as `dict` and you are returting a list or set.

```
    @app.route('/newProjectCreation/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def newProjectCreation():
        try:
            if request.method == 'POST':
                # Data Fetch from Models Form
                name = request.form('modelName')
                modelDescription = request.form('modelDescription')
                inputType = request.form.getlist('inputType[]')
                outputType = request.form.getlist('outputType[]')
                model = request.files('model')
                modelLanguage = request.form('modelLanguage')
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, I tried the solution, but a slight change: all the  ```[]``` won't be replaced with ```()``` it's just for the fields of "inputType" and "outputType" that will be changed.

Comment: But now another problem arises in the line where I take a file input (second last line).

Comment: Please share the error. No one can predict the error as you do not share [MRC] (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Second Error--> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67481914/typeerror-unhashable-type-set-in-flask-form-while-uploading-file

Please Check and advice.